# Is it possible to disable "Post questions once in every 20 minute"?

Tags: support, privileges, new-users, rate-limiting, asking-questions

When I tried to post more than 2 questions one after other, Stack Overflow said me that "You can only post once every 20 minutes."

Is this restriction can be removed or disabled? Or, does this restriction get automatically removed when I got particular number of reputation points?

Comment: It's fine that you guys' answer to the question is NO, but why downvote? I see the question itself is not of a bad quality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, [there are some relaxations at higher reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/175248), namely:

> - Users < 125 rep, 20 minutes
> - Users < 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 60 seconds
> - Users > 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 30 seconds

So, if you're below 125 reputation, you're only going to be allowed to ask one question in twenty minutes.  A user that's between that and 10K reputation trips the Captcha if they ask more than once within 60 seconds.  It's even further relaxed past 10K reputation.

The basic rationale [can be found at Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking/); the main idea being that you don't want to allow new users to flood the site with tons of questions before they've had a chance to truly think about if they need to ask another one *immediately* after.

Answer (score 13):

Rate limiting questions serves two purposes, the first being a guard rail to help ensure folks put sufficient thought into their questions. You might have, say, 10 questions all lined up yet the premise of 9 of them depend on assumptions you make in the first - which could turn out to be completely off base. It also helps folks to re-read their drafts (almost everyone can benefit from this). While it can be frustrating for people that consistently ask great questions, it has a huge positive impact on quality.

It also helps to avoid unfortunate things like this ...

[image: Because this happened]

You'll see throttling in place almost *everywhere* human beings can push buttons and pull levers, it's just a good idea to have. We relax things as it becomes apparent that limiting becomes a hardship for levels of participation that we really want, with relax being the operative word. It relaxes as the system begins to trust you.

A few good posts is all you need to keep it from bothering you for the most part.

Answer (score 8):

This restriction is only in place for users with less than 125 reputation ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)). There are also additional restrictions on questions, no matter what your reptuation:

- maximum of 6 questions per day
- maximum of 50 questions per 30 days

The restriction is in place to try and make the questioner check that their question is coherent, doesn't have any spelling or gramatical errors, and that they've included as much information about the issue as possible.

While this can be slightly annoying if you've been preparing a bunch of questions for a while in an external text editor, some people just try and post 10 similar questions in the space of an hour.

Often, these are badly worded, unclear, and (most of the time) can be easily answered with a little bit of research. If you haven't already done so, it's a good idea to try and do some research if possible before asking a bunch of questions.