# Questions are now rate-limited to 1 per 90 minutes?

Tags: support, asking-questions, new-users, rate-limiting

I'm unable to post any question at Stack Overflow. It says "You can only post once every 90 minutes". I faced this issue yesterday as well. Was this changed from the previous 20 minutes? If so, why?

[image]

Comment: Is anyone else at your location also posting questions?

Comment: This is my workplace. So may be someone in the same network may have posted a question using his own id. Does that matters?

Comment: yes i posted a question 15 minutes ago, before posting second one.

Comment: Then why is the error message a surprise? Why do you *have* to ask questions that often?

Comment: Looks like you have been given time to make sure your question is **excellent**. Full of relevant detail, spell checked, good formatting and so on.

Comment: @Oded: should the FAQ be updated? It claims a low-rep user can post a question every 20 minutes. The 90 minutes limit here is new to me.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Question i posted today(15 mins ago) is the question i was trying to post yesterday, but was unable to post because of that message. I have never seen that message before. So, that's why the surprise. FYI, i have not posted any question since last week.

Comment: @Kanav: see, that's what should have been part of your question to begin with. I suspect that there are rate limits *per IP address* in place as well as per account, to prevent people trying to work around the rate limits by creating new accounts. Which is why I asked if anyone else on the same network is posting questions as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - AFAIK, it is still 20 minutes everywhere else.

Comment: @Martijn The 90 minutes is a recent change, Shog talked about it [here, towards the end](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/366904). Presumably the SO-specific FAQ should be updated, it's just not exactly high-priority.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable "Post questions once in every 20 minute"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251416/is-it-possible-to-disable-post-questions-once-in-every-20-minute)

Comment: This is new behavior, actually, so not _quite_ a duplicate.

Comment: related: [Error — “you can only post once every 90 minutes” but I haven't posted in days](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259941/error-you-can-only-post-once-every-90-minutes-but-i-havent-posted-in-days). "The rate limit applies to IP addresses (until you reach 125 points...)"

Comment: Honestly, I can respect 20 minutes so that people are at least thinking about their question but 90? What if we run into 2 different problems well before 90 minutes is up? I usually stick to the Excel-VBA topics so if I am coding all day, I can run into numerous problems within 30 min. With 1 question every hour and a half I will never get anything answered.

Answer (score 69):

This is in place because folks need to see questions ***as a consumable resource that can be depleted***, so that they:

- Ask questions *only* when they really need to, presumably after some research hasn't paid off
- Make questions that they ask count *more*, presumably because they've *done some research*.

If you need to ask questions more than every 1.5 hours, you *probably* aren't putting enough thought, time or both into your questions, which isn't fair to us, as it diminishes the perceived quality of the resource we're working very hard to build and maintain.

Note, this setting is only different on Stack Overflow, the limit is a bit higher on the rest of the sites in our network. We had to increase the amount of time folks need to wait until they become established users because *people would request that we help them through every task they undertook during their work day*. This is supposed to be Q&A, not pair programming.

It's a bit unfortunate for those that *do* ask good questions right off the bat, and bless you if you're in that very small minority - it won't take long for you to establish yourself, perhaps just one question could do it.

This is one step in some changes that we're making to stop those that don't actually *learn* anything by asking questions, and just continue to throw themselves at a brick wall with down voted upon down voted questions. It's not a good experience for *them*, and it's certainly not a good experience for *us*, so we're changing the system to intercede a bit sooner and slow folks down until they *do* learn how to ask better questions, or give up entirely.

Comment: "Can I ask you a question?" "Yes, in 90 minutes."

Comment: "OK it's been 90 minutes. Can I ask now?" "You just did." "But I—" "Please try again in 90 minutes."

Comment: Its been 5hours I posted my last question. I try to post another question now. I am getting "You can only post once every 90 minutes.". Any clue????

Comment: related request to get this at Programmers (and possibly at Code Review and Code Golf as well): [Please increase rate limit for new users asking questions to one used at Stack Overflow (1 per 90 minutes)](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6844/31260)

Comment: Just to be clear, does the 90 minute interval apply to _all_ users, or only those below the "established user" privilege level as your third- and second-to-last paragraphs hint at?

Comment: Can we extend this to apply to all users and not allow established users to bypass it? Why would anyone have more than one question every 90 minutes if they're doing proper research?

Comment: @KevinB Because they are researching multiple problems at once? Because for some problems it is possible to be confident that there is no available answer with less than 90 minutes of research? Because they spend the day working and in the evening they have time/freedom to post questions for problems they weren't able to solve all day? Regardless, it sucks to be one of the "very small minority" who are trying to be good citizens and still get hit by this. Fortunately, reading this meta and composing a comment has used up most of my 40 minute ban - one more coffee and I'm good to go ;)

Comment: Good time to leave stack overflow and provide a truly helpful alternative. Some helpers (such as Kevin B) are not so helpful and withhold answers they have to user's questions. There's a lot of arrogance and I've noticed that more and more helpers spend more time giving lessons than genuinely helping.