# Error -- "you can only post once every 90 minutes" but I haven't posted in days

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I tried to post a SO question this morning, but I got an error saying:

> You can only post once every 90 minutes.

However, I haven't posted in days, let alone 90 minutes.

What gives?

Comment: Anyone else on your IP address posting? Are you posting from the office, for example?

Comment: Indeed -- I am posting from my office.

Comment: Until you have enough reputation, other posts from you *ip address* also count. Otherwise people just create new accounts to bypass the rate limit.

Comment: That stinks.  What kind of rep do I need to avoid this problem?  I'm in a big office, so tracking down the other poster will be very hard.

Comment: I don't see a rep requirement in [the post announcing this feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256324/1043380).

Comment: @gunr2171: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899)

Comment: Same question , I posted in Magento Community and after that I tried to post to stackoverflow but I can not

Answer (score 177):

The rate limit applies to *IP addresses* (until you reach 125 points, see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)).

Most likely, someone else has posted a question from the same IP address. If you are in an office, most probably one of your co-workers posted a question, and you'll have to wait a little.

The rate limit has to apply this broadly because otherwise users can create new accounts to bypass the limits.

Comment: I think this is a sign that the warning message needs to be improved, though. Saying "**You** can only post..." does not immediately suggest that "**Your IP Address** can only post..." as well.

Comment: I'm not sure, MDeSchaepmeester - I mean, I would suspect a scenario like this doesn't happen all that often. That said, only posting every 90 minutes seems peculiar - I'd expect something with a rolling window.

Comment: So its like stop using stackoverflow  in office OR if you want to use waste your 90 minutes. What is the point in restricting from a public IP ? I face this kind of situation while booking tatkal railway tickets where this kind of restriction matters.

Comment: If you run into the scenario where someone else is posting from your ip address you can try posting your question with your Smart Phone.

Comment: It shouldn't be limited by IP it should be by user.

Comment: @damau: if only people didn't keep creating new accounts, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters this isn't a loaded set of questions but .. what's the evidence that people do keep creating accounts as opposed to many new users from the same IP coming from a company?  What's the advantage of creating many accounts?  Trolling?  Why would you want to post shed loads of questions under many user accounts?  Maybe a tad naive maybe but just wondering.

Comment: @damau: We see people creating additional accounts to try and bypass limits all the time. I'm not going to go into the details of how we know it is not different people, the moderator toolset is deliberately kept in shadows to avoid gaming.

Comment: Just to add another point: If you're running into other people on your network causing you to not be able to post questions, there is such a thing as a proxy. They can be very useful when being blocked from doing legitimate things (like posting an SO question) by tools designed to prevent people from doing illegitimate things (like spamming SO) that look similar to the server. [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) can be a useful tool at times, for example. (Mods, feel free to delete this if you'd rather this suggestion not be here.)

Comment: I had to ssh into my home machine to post a question but at least it worked!

Comment: @Eric I'm not sure how that'd work, as your Smart Phone will be on the same Wi-Fi network and thus have the same NAT IP address.

Comment: @tepples: Not if you use the mobile network.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Using the mobile network throttles you when another mobile user behind the same [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) IP address posts a question. In addition, subscribing to mobile data in addition to the Internet that you're already paying for at work or home costs money every month. Additional payment turns SO into ExpertS-exChange, the very thing that SO was created to avoid.

Comment: @tepples why are you telling me? I only explained what another commenter probably meant. If you don't want to use a mobile network to access Stack Overflow then don't.

Comment: @EverybodyElseWhoHappensAcrossThis Mostly I was pointing out, for the benefit of _anyone_ reading this, a plausible situation in which a new user would have to either get 62 suggested edits accepted or pay for access in order to be able to ask a _first_ question.

Comment: let me get this straight, unless you have earned 125 reps , you can hardly post anything while working in office , because every 90 mins someone would've already posted, and mine is a very big office. right??  I think stackoverflow should work on this , and come up with a better solution. Because it's annoying when most of the time you have to stay in office.

Comment: @RaJ: 125 points isn't that hard to get. It's not a perfect solution, but this is an imperfect world with loads of low-quality dross coming in from the same IP address.

Comment: @Martijin : yeah..that should be considered as well, i'm thankfull that atleast i can comment. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've got the same problem as steampowered. Is this a bug which could be fixed at some point?

Comment: @Dbl: it's not a bug. It is by design. You can't post more than once every 90 minutes, on any Stack Exchange site, from the same IP address.

Comment: wait a little :D -> in a company with ten-thousands of developers  :)!

Comment: Many years later, this is still pretty dumb. An abuser can use the same workarounds that is provided for honest users and a non-office setup can fairly easily reset their IP.

Answer (score 73):

You might try to post from your mobile until the time limit is over.

Comment: why is this down-voted? if you are on a mobile network instead of the communal Wifi, this is perfectly legit.

Comment: @cneuro Downvoters likely either A. have a habit of using Wi-Fi where available in order to make the most of their (expensive) monthly data allowance, or B. have a carrier that puts a bunch of subscribers behind NAT (which is most of them), or C. have a low-end mobile that can't post to Stack Overflow in the first place.

Comment: The question isn't *asking* for a workaround (at least, not explicitly). It's asking for an *explanation* of a seemingly incorrect error message.

Answer (score 13):

This happened to me when I attempted to move a post from one stackexchange site to another.  I deleted the post on the first site, then attempted to post the question on another site.

I remoted into a computer at a different IP address using the same account, and then stackexchange permitted me to make the second post without the time constraint.  You must have access to multiple IP addresses to make posts close together, even if you delete the old posts occurring during the time window.

Comment: I have tried posting it yesterday..and trying it again today....it is showing the same message. I don't know if since yesterday 90 mins are not yet over for the system.

Comment: @JGS Maybe somebody else using your IP has already posted again in the past 90 minutes.

Comment: @vonludi I would hope the wrote the software to identify users using cookies and not IP addresses.

Answer (score 6):

I just encountered the same problem using my school network.
I bypassed the problem by using a VPN (opera browser has one built-in)