# How can I find out when the last question from my ip address was posted?

Tags: support

I'm running up against the 90 min question block although I personally have not posted in the past ninty minutes. ([Error -- "you can only post once every 90 minutes" but I haven't posted in days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259941/3303546)) . I would like to know how long ago the post was made from my ip address, so that I can post my question promptly when the block expires. Had I posted, I could simply look at my activity history and find out when the last post was made, but as it is I'd have to ask everyone in the office who last posted.

Is there a way to find out how long I have to wait based on the ip address?

Comment: No, there isn't.  That's [PII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information).  Even if you knew this, someone on the same IP address could get a question in under your radar, and you'd still have to wait.

Comment: _"I'd have to ask everyone in the office who last posted"_ - is your office that large? How often does this occur?

Comment: My office is maybe 25-30 people who use SO/E on a regular basis @CodeCaster. But, once you take corporate proxies into account there's thousands of people coming out of 4 main data centres; most aren't coders, but you can't ask everyone on the continent when they last posted. I can see this being a problem...

Comment: @CodeCaster Honestly, it's not that many people (~40), but it's a large building (six floors) and I don't know which computers share my ip (maybe all?). I'd feel a bit foolish wandering around asking people, some who I've not even met, if they recently posted something.

Comment: This is why we need IPv6 deployed everywhere :).

Answer (score 6):

You can't. How would that help you? Normally, there won't be any contention at the end of 90 minutes - you just got unlucky this time. If there *is* contention, then anyone else trying to post would have access to the same information, and will be trying to post at the exact same time.

Comment: As it is, there is asymmetric information. The person who did post knows when the 90 minutes will expire. Other SO users sharing the IP address do not.

Comment: If you have one person dedicated to asking a bunch of questions as quickly as possible, you're screwed anyway... At least until they hit the other daily caps.

Comment: I agree that I just got unlucky. I went home and posted from there instead. Usually, waiting to post the question isn't a bad thing either. I was mostly just curious.

Comment: There's contention if you're posting from home and home is behind a neighborhood-sized CGNAT.

Answer (score 0):

if you know about who are on the same IP address,you can visit their profile and get the time of his/her last post . Note that it is possible if there are only less no of peoples share the same IP address.(that is what i does..!!)