# Is only the latest IP used in a question-ban?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, post-ban

Quote from the answer in this [Meta Wiki question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th):

> An automatic filter is in place to ban questions and/or answers **from
> IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor posts.**

As has been [discussed before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267025/is-it-a-good-idea-to-have-an-ip-level-question-ban) on Meta, banning a users' IP address could result in many Stack Overflow users being question-banned (I believe this has been resolved now); let's put that in a different perspective, such as a timeline of events (an example, this isn't *my* timeline :-)):

- Monday: ***User registered on Stack Overflow (this is a new account).*** Asked crappy question, receives -5 votes and the question is removed by a moderator. Was in a public library,
- Tuesday: Provided a good answer to a bad question, receives +3/-1 votes. At work.
- Wednesday: Answer on Tuesday is chosen as the best answer by the asker and is accepted. At home.
- Thursday: Asked ***yet another crappy question***, -8 votes and the question is closed. At home.
- Friday: Posted *another* crappy question, downvoted -1. Tried to post another question but the user is now question-banned. At work. (***Phew! This user is pretty bad!***)

Will ***all*** those places be under an IP-address question-ban, or would the ban only apply in the last location the account was logged into?

AKA: Will the IP-ban apply to the public library, work, and home, or just home?

Comment: IP addresses are only used for low-rep users, afaik the threshold is <100 rep (possibly <200). This is in place to prevent people from creating a ton of new accounts to circumvent bans and blocks. It has nothing to do with any blocks of your account.

Comment: @l4mpi ***Which is why I mentioned that the user registered on Stack Overflow on the Monday.***

Comment: Obligatory question: why do you (or why would we) need to know this?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm interested.

Answer (score 4):

Given that the user is the same user, logged in using the same credentials, there will be no IP ban.

The account will be getting the ban.

---

IP bans happen when lots of posts come in from the same IP and a large amount of them are bad.

Comment: I had the assumption that IP bans are also applied to new and low reputation users

Comment: @cybermonkey - if we know it is the same user, why would we use the IP?

Comment: As mentioned here (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), IP addresses and accounts are blocked when those accounts have a history of asking low-quality questions.

Comment: Yes. That doesn't contradict what I said.

Comment: You said `if we know it is the same user why would we use the IP?`, so yes, it contradicts that. In the instance a user is both IP blocked and account-blocked, would this block 'follow' them around (as in would any IP address they use be blocked in this way)? They could simply create a new account and post away if it didn't.

Comment: You are making the assumption that we block IPs when we know the users. I don't know what is a user that is IP blocked - there is no such thing - there are users that are blocked and there are IPs that are blocked. Two separate things that you are conflating.