# What to do when a question you answered gets deleted intentionally?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, new-users, behavior

I have answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185374/how-to-find-the-index-of-all-the-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string-i-have-only) (<s>not view-able anymore since it was deleted...</s>) about an hour ago.

After taking the time to answer, and replying to the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5871713/user5871713)'s (a new user on the site - 2 days old) **many** comments and further questions, he accepted my answer.

Then I noticed that about 20 minutes later he unaccepted my answer and deleted the question.

I suspect this was done because the question was about a specific course he was taking in school and didn't want to get caught cheating (I say this because in one of his comments he said "I can't paste the entire code/question here because I will get thrown out of the course").

Is there anything to do to deter this kind of behavior in the future? As far as I can see he could just asking questions and deleting them, therefore bypassing the whole point of Stack Overflow altogether.

Edit: the question just got undeleted, by a moderator <s>or by the user (my guess is moderator)</s>. All the comments on the answer except 1 (mine) are still deleted.

Comment: This is (yet another reason) why you don't do other people's homework for them.

Comment: I answered before knowing this, and the question contained code and an attempt with a clear question

Comment: Get a hold of a mod (normally by flagging one of the OP's posts, but since they don't have any visible to you... hopefully this meta post will do it).  The mods can fix it (alternatively 20k+ users can vote to undelete I believe).  They shouldn't be able to delete things like that to cover up their cheating.

Comment: @Becuzz:  Would you be interested in posting that as an answer?

Comment: @Makoto I could (and will if someone still thinks it is worth it) but it looks like Brad Larson's answer pretty much has it covered.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, only [0.6% of reasonable (not downvoted or close voted) questions that receive at least one answer are deleted by their owner shortly after they receive that answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313854). [14% of users who do this end up getting some kind of ban, and 11% will do it more than once.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313854#comment289380_313857). So, if you only answer reasonable questions, there is 0.6% chance of this happening. However, if you answer low quality questions, all bets are off.

Comment: The question in itself is not so bad (anymore). -21 for that doesn't seem that fair.

Comment: @eis yea that is kind of people exerting their anger towards that user "bad behavior" I guess X_x. The question itself is definitely not bad..

Comment: This question is so much better than it's title...

Comment: I am shocked that no one thought to close the question as a duplicate.  I have a hard time believing that such a question has never been asked before in *any* language.

Comment: I know I've deleted questions in the past - questions which at the time seemed perfectly OK but a few hours later seemed pretty dumb. As the asker of a question, I would be pretty upset if I felt I no longer had control over my own questions. The asker of a question has some special privileges on their own question, including the right to accept whatever answer they like, even if the rest of the world things it is a crap answer. For my money, I think that should extend to the power of ultimate veto over the question as a whole.

Comment: @Tim Long in some cases I would agree, but in this case it is certain that the OP deleted the question to avoid getting caught cheating on his course. He said so himself.

Comment: I just realized: Do questions ever get deleted unintentionally?

Comment: @Cerbrus Depends on whose intentions you're referring to. All deletions are *someone's* intentions, but they might not be the intention of the asker. The roomba deletes plenty of questions automatically. Like [this recent example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317961/request-to-undelete-community-auto-delete).

Comment: That recent example is a rather poor question, though.

Comment: The question is now locked.

Comment: is the OP considered as hoarding knowledge ? for whatever reason,  such OPs obviously do NOT want their question and corresponding answers to be visible by other people who hit similar questions in the future. To me school homework is just one of lame excuses for OPs deleting questions

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In this case, I undeleted the question because I hate seeing when people try to take their ball and go home. With your edits, it's not a terrible question, and your answer provides general value.

Had your answer been upvoted (as it is now), they would not have been able to delete their question. As part of a recent discussion about this, [I proposed that this deletion block be extended to questions with *any* answers on them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315406/19679). Not saying that's the best solution, just something we could think about here.

As for the user, self-deletions count against you in the question-ban heuristics, so if they do this repeatedly they will quickly find themselves unable to ask any questions at all. That's a measure intended to curb this kind of abuse.

We regularly decline flags from students who try to have moderators delete their questions if there's any value at all in the answers. If you do think there is value in a question or answer that a user has self-deleted, flag it and let us know why you think it should be undeleted. We can undelete if we think there's merit to your request.

Comment: Leaving the Q&A around is probably a better deterrent than the contributions to the ban algorithm; such immoral students are probably on a one-account-per-question scheme anyway. If the Q&A could at least be preserved until the next semester to give the prof/TA time to spot it and award the student an F-, then great:)

Comment: In fact, it might help if there was a flag for 'suspected homework' that profs could use to help search for outsource-to SO cheats.  I'm guessing that's been proposed already - I'll search meta tomorrow when I sober up.

Comment: @MartinJames - In particularly egregious cases, moderators have been known to write professors about cheating or large volumes of questions coming from their classes (without using any moderator-private information, of course). I just got a response from one such professor, along with a BCC on a rather instructional email they sent to their entire class. This can be a very effective form of bad question prevention.

Comment: lol 'rather instructional email'.  If that email threatens massive fines and/or immediate course expulsion for violations, I'm all for it:)

Comment: @BradLarson As I read your answer and got to the part of the question ban [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267025/1195056) came to mind, and might not be a bad thing to reference as it hasn't been discussed in a while (unless it is no longer valid).

Comment: Don't forget to mention http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/7757 when contacting course instructors

Comment: I had answered a question at work and was curious about the actual performance gain for my suggestions.  By the time I looked again at home the question had been deleted and therefore I can't see my answer:-(  Someone had even taken the time to down vote my answer without reasoning why leaving my answer on minus figures.

Comment: The question has since been deleted again.

Comment: Yeah it was. @BradLarson why did it get deleted again?

Comment: @Idos Moderators are not the only ones who are able to (un)delete posts. Users with high enough rep can vote to delete a question if they don't think it is worth keeping on the site. I would guess that's what happened here.

Comment: Oh, now it's back. I can hardly handle all this excitement.

Comment: @Idos Sorry; I was the third person to vote to delete it. I didn't realize it was being discussed on meta, I just saw a question that had over 40+ downvotes so I thought we would be better off without it.

Comment: @Josh Crozier: Therein lies the dilemma of how to decide whether to keep or delete a question with 40+ downvotes. There's a good answer here, but surely that would raise the question of why the question has so many downvotes, then.

Comment: @BoltClock Given it's a dupe now. Why not merge[?](https://i.imgflip.com/yoaso.jpg)

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: We don't merge duplicates unless they are exact copies.

Comment: @BradLarson the post got deleted *again*, I flagged this post a few hours ago for a mod, but I would love if I could get an explanation/permanent fix to this. Maybe actually merge my answer to the duplicate question (I can edit it a little to make it appropriate).

Comment: @Idos - It's shameful how things that appear on Meta get piled on this way. Also, I see at least one name on there from someone who blindly deletes everything he sees. Undeleted.

Comment: Thanks Brad! Is there any way to prevent this from happening again? Or if someone blindly deletes everything isn't it a problem and needs an audit of some sort?

Comment: @Idos I think the primary problem why this is occurring is because of the mod tools page given to 10k+ users. This question is at the top of the most negative question (and will stay for 60 days) and hence people are jumping to delete it. (It has a delete vote now -- http://i.stack.imgur.com/uR52G.png). The next time it happens, don't worry. Come to either the Python room or SOCVR and inform us. We will undelete it. There is no need to disturb Brad or other mods. :-)

Comment: Yeah but the real question is can they delete again after a mod undeletes? Thus, the war continues...

Comment: might be dumb question but ...... how to flag a user if he/she already deleted the post in such situation ?

Answer (score 17):

I see that this was not a clear-cut case because the original question was not an obvious “send me teh codez” question.

In general, however, the best way to avoid such situations is to refrain from answering low-quality questions in the first place. I rarely see selfish homework questions being asked as well-written posts so this heuristic works pretty well. If in doubt about the OP's attitude, for example, try commenting with a link to the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) suggesting them to improve their question. If they cannot be bothered to do so, they are probably not worth your time anyway. Just down-vote and walk away.

If the question is valuable and you post a good answer, as soon as your answer gets the first up-vote, the OP will no longer be able to delete their question (see: “[How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/)”). As a last resort, flag for moderator attention as was already suggested by Brad Larson.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good tip. I didn't actually know that after only 1 upvote he can't delete the question!

Answer (score -4):

IMO, this is still too broad, even with the improvements you made on it. Basically the OP has some code that wants to adapt to new requirements, but he didn't even tried to do any work. I'd recommend to have this question closed for one more reason: if the OP tries to cover his tracks by editing the question, then, if closed, the question will automatically appear on the reopen review queue, which means reviewer with good judgements can rollback the edit if necessary.

Comment: Users don't *need* to try anything for their question to be narrowly scoped enough for Stack Overflow. Posting their attempt merely turns the question from a "How to" question into a debugging style question. Debugging style questions can be too broad even with an MCVE, and "How to" questions can be too broad without code, but a "How to" question not having code does not in and of itself make the question too broad. With many "how to" questions, code in the question is actually just noise. A lack of research (being easily googleable) is a downvote reason, not a close vote reason.

Comment: @TinyGiant most likely questions that can be found on google search have already been answered here on SO, so they are duplicate.

Comment: Sure, close it as a duplicate if there is one. Close it as off-topic if it is off-topic. Close it as opinion based if it is opinion based. Don't close it as too broad just because it doesn't contain code if it is otherwise narrowly scoped. Don't close it just because it is lacking in research effort. For the love of all that is good and honest in the world, don't close it as debugging/MCVE if it isn't a debugging question. Downvote questions that you think do not show any research effort, are unclear or not useful. Comment on any question you think can be improved.

Comment: There are enough questions in the Close Vote Queue already, we don't need to be adding valid on-topic narrowly-scoped questions onto the pile just because they lack research effort, someone doesn't like them, they are uninteresting or poorly worded, etc. There is a lot more to moderation of Q&A than just throwing close votes around like candy.

Comment: @TinyGiant either duplicate or too broad, the question still ends up in the close queue. And yes, I know there are a lot of question in that queue (I review on that queue on a daily basis), but not flagging a question because the queue it would end up into is too big is not reasonable. Closed questions get deleted  after a while, while downvoted ones remain in the system, and they just pollute.

Comment: I didn't say you should not close a question because of the size of the queue. I said you shouldn't be wasting close votes on questions which don't actually warrant close votes, while mentioning the size of the queue as one of the reasons why this should not be done. If a question is actually too broad for stack overflow, close it as too broad, but don't base that decision solely off of whether or not the question contains code or shows research effort. Voting to Close a question for those reasons is doing a disservice to the asker, and the users in the queue who then have to vote leave open

Comment: Way to completely remove all semblance of context from my statement and focus on a single phrase by the way.

Comment: This particular question says "This is my code... I want something extra from it". IMO, this qualifies for a broad question. More, there's already a almost identical question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list). So either way, the question qualifies for being closed. In this particular case the question is a duplicate, but most of the homework questions are too localized to find a duplicated, and 99% of them are too broad.

Comment: @Cristik That's not a duplicate question of that question; this is asking for words in a string, that is asking for items in a list.  As far as being "too broad", it's not; just because someone says "I want to do this, how" doesn't make it a broad question if whatever "this" refers to is *not* in of itself, too broad.

Comment: @Cristik The reason it's not too broad is the same as Shog lays out in his answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224104/16587

Comment: @GeorgeStocker got it, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -9):

Sometimes (though obviously not in this scenario) users will realize they have asked the wrong question. Often (exactly like exceptionally poor bug reports at Mozilla and perfect bug reports that get thrown out the window without the slightest regard irrespective of the intense amount of effort on the behalf of clarity and quality of the second bug poster) first posts are from what I've seen held in higher regard than quality posts in *absolute*, at least in my experience. This becomes extremely discouraging to quality posters.

Altruism is important so quality posters like myself will occasionally delete a question because we lack *any* intention to follow up on a question we *thought* was previously relevant and want to avoid adding clutter and contributing to the very common low quality questions that end up leading to duplicate questions.

Essentially the duplicate function is extremely flawed as first option is not always the best option so it is in everyone's interest to have a basic voting system to determine which question (when the context is exactly the same) has better clarity as well as a third option to vote against duplication as some moderators *very often do not consider the context of a question and blindly mark it as a duplicate*.