# Request to undelete community auto delete

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645050/find-when-a-file-was-deleted-on-github) on Jan 6 and forgot to check for updates on it.

It took me a while to realize it had been deleted as it was over 30 days old and had a score of -1.

In my opinion this is a perfectly valid question. I cannot understand the down vote on the question since as far as I can see it is well formatted and suitable for the site.

If anyone has advice on how to improve it I will happily do so.

Answer (score 4):

I undeleted it, but there's no guarantee that it's not going to get removed again on the next pass (the check runs weekly) if it still meets the deletion criteria then.