# 'We should be focusing on the post, not the poster' is not working well :(

Tags: discussion

I'm getting tired of the homework vamps who delete their question as soon as they get their code to work.  It's just happened again, and the commenter who had finally managed to find the most serious bug, (for they were Legion), was prevented from copying to an answer and getting rep.

There is one obvious band-aid.  The vamps who indulge in such practices tend to have low rep, so I could look at the posters' rep first.  If it's less than 20, no need to risk wasting any further time on the question.

There are additional advantageous side-effects:

1. I won't need to spend so much time on dup-searches for 'writing out-of-bounds on my array does not cause a segfault' #00472953.
2. I will not see the 50k+ rep-personalServicesWorkers answering obviously multi-duped questions instead of marking them as dup and so I won't waste my own rep on downvoting them all.
3. Less experienced/skilled users can answer those questions and, if the 50k+ PSW don't take it all, gain rep.
4. I have a better chance of spending what time I have on better questions.

I can't see much advantage for me, or SO in general, in engaging with questions from low reps.

I'm sorry, but focusing on the post, not the poster, does not seem to work. I don't want to seem 'elitist', 'hostile' etc, but I've had enough of continual abuse by posters :(.

Comment: Yes, it's true that most bad questions come from low rep users, but that's because most questions *period* come from low rep users.  In my experience the more rep a question author has, the less likely it is to be a good question.  Most high-rep users asking questions are the help vampires that ask several questions every single day over the course of years about topics that they should have been able to figure out with a few weeks worth of programming experience.  Virtually all of the great questions I see are from low rep users, typically 1 rep users.

Comment: As far as help vampires deleting their bad questions as soon as they get an answer; that's why you don't answer bad questions.

Comment: FYI - We are looking at possibly [blocking users from self-deleting questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276027/should-heavily-edited-answers-block-self-deletion-of-questions) because of the problems it causes. We posted about it on MSE.  Instead of blocking based on edits, [we're also looking at preventing deletions based on length of answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276053/164200).

Comment: Well, look on the bright side.  There are only two kind of people that can delete another user's post with a single action.  Moderators and no-rep users.  We should have an election to let them in :)

Comment: [I had a meta post about this very issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316117/what-to-do-when-a-question-you-answered-gets-deleted-intentionally) and the question got un-deleted as a result (albeit after a long back-and-forth of delete-undelete disputes). Should really have a permanent fix to this though.

Comment: lol, PersonalServiceWorkers

Comment: A user self-deleting a question with extensive debugging in the comments would perhaps be moderator-attention flag-worthy? It can get the question undeleted, and the shitty behaviour gets on their "record"...

Comment: "was prevented from copying to an answer and getting rep." Good! They shouldn't be answering bad questions anyway Hopefully they'll learn.

Comment: @juanchopanza What makes you think that only bad questions can have a solution mentioned in a comment?

Comment: @TylerH I didn't say any such thing. I am not sure where you got that notion from. Bad questions should not even have a solution mentioned in comments.

Comment: @juanchopanza Your quote indicates that questions who receive a solution in the comments are bad. Where do you get "bad questions" from in that quote?

Comment: @TylerH "the commenter who had finally managed to find the most serious bug, (for they were Legion)" Legion bugs -> bad question.

Comment: @TylerH I am serious, but I am failing to understand your logic. My quote indicates it is a good thing the "commenter" failed to upload an answer to a bad question, because hopefully they wasted a lot of time on it and they learnt that answering bad questions is a bad thing. It isn't very complicated.

Comment: @juanchopanza From just the words you quoted, it's impossible to tell the quality of a question. If you meant purely in the context of a specific question, that's different, and requires specifying *which* question. As for a question about code with multiple bugs, that is not at all a guarantee that the question is of poor quality. If the most serious bug is the one giving the asker a problem/the one they ask about, then any other bugs are irrelevant, anyway.

Comment: @TylerH A question full of irrelevant bugs is a bad question. Guaranteed. Period. End of.

Comment: @juanchopanza What a myopic view. Clearly we disagree on what constitutes a poor question.

Comment: I think stack should ask you what kind of programmer you are and work around that.

Comment: [Here is another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899070/php-multiplication-table-with-set-column-and-row-header).

Comment: There is always a certain risk of answering low quality questions. All possible bad things can happen to them.

Comment: I've always understood the 'We should be focusing on the post, not the poster' advice to have more to do with closing, deleteing, flagging, policy discussion, etc., rather than what you choose to pay attention to.  What you pay attention to, read or answer is up to you.  Personally, I only read things posted by people who have at least one "m" in their user name, and I'll be damned if you can tell me to do otherwise.

Answer (score 124):

Why is a homework vamp deleting their question a bad thing?

Deletion robs answerers of the rep they might have gotten from posting an answer to a homework question.  The clear message they receive is that they may not earn any reputation from such questions, and perhaps they'll stop answering them.

Self-deletion of poor questions is a very good thing.  It relieves us of the close/delete cycle that most bad questions have to undergo.

Of course, in the unlikely event that a student has somehow managed to post an Academy Award winning question, by all means cast a moderator flag and ask for undeletion.

And, of course, all it takes is *a single upvote on the answer* to prevent deletion.

All that said, I would be in favor of a period of time (somewhere between 1 and 24 hours) in which the OP cannot delete their question unless the question is closed or no answers are posted.

Comment: I like that last sentence the best - it allows some time for an upvote on a worthy answer to happen (if it will), while still enabling the self-deletion cleanup.

Comment: Yes, this. Was going to say the same thing. It's good for answerers to lose rep over bad questions. They'll learn not to answer them, which will discourage users from asking them in the first place.

Comment: Sometimes even a vampire can ask an interesting question.

Comment: @JDB If that's the intended effect, why not give less or 0 rep for answering a closed question, and *subtract* rep for answering a deleted one?

Comment: @immibis Among other reasons, sometimes questions are improperly closed or deleted. I think a grand waste of time is better than punitive rep loss, making the later unnecessary.

Comment: @canon: I can attest to this - seen the occasional interesting question asked by a vamp and found myself in a dilemma of answering a question for being interesting that was asked by someone known for consistently bad questions.

Comment: The last paragraph is actually the missing thing, or is it already implemented.

Comment: Question, do we really want a single up vote to stop deletion?  If the answer has multiple down votes and a single up vote that still stops deletion, do we want that?

Comment: It also has a side effect. A very active user I know answered a bad question and got +10 upvotes (including mine) stopped answering with the same pace after the deletion of that question. _Not all questions can be salvaged and not all what is asked is a good question. But maintaining a good answerer is maintaining the health of this site_

Comment: " I would be in favor of a period of time (somewhere between 1 and 24 hours) in which the OP cannot delete their question": well, sometimes self-deletion prevents the user from getting more downvotes. Preventing users to do that would be cruel.

Answer (score 43):

Just my musings, but perhaps we should make users choose from a preset list of options, *a la* the close-vote modal, for why they are self-deleting, such as (just pulling these out of thin air):

- I don't think my question is on-topic, after all.
- I have discovered my problem and solved it myself.
- I am no longer interested in a solution for this problem.

Options #2 and #3, especially #2, could pop up one of those signature red banners saying "*Are you sure?* Please reconsider; SO is a place for knowledge, post your solution as an answer, instead, or check this box to have a moderator disassociate the question from your account" or something. This could help to educate these users and reduce the amount of self-deletions we receive.

Another benefit is that instead of seeing the message* "this question was deleted by the asker", we'd see contextually helpful information and would know better how to proceed.

* As I understand it, only < 10K users see this message, and > 10K users can already act on deleted questions by voting to undelete or flagging for a moderator. Maybe this message could be visible even for 10K users if something like that were implemented.

Comment: And delete option two could encourage them to self-answer instead.

Comment: I am interested in option number 3 too, as help vampires might be able to choose it dissociate the question from their account (or put in a request for it).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't solve the problem. Homework posters who wish to cover their tracks *want* their questions gone, they will learn to choose the first option very quickly.

Comment: Honestly though - "off topic" is about the only one of those I consider "valid". Because part of the point of SO is that we're collating answers to questions for _everyone_ to reference. So - if you've solved it, answer it. (Or let someone else answer it). If you're not interested any more... OK, but maybe someone else is.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Very few problems on this site are entirely solvable. My suggestion, while admittedly being thrown together in a few minutes, is only an attempt to *lessen* the problem. An easement, if you will. Something more intense or more permanent might be jarring to the UX, especially if it fails.

Comment: @Sobrique Right... hence why options #2 and #3 would produce a Big Red Warning telling the OP that such a reason might not be valid and offering alternative paths that would retain the question.

Comment: @Sobrique Depends on how much effort poster and others put into it, and whether it can be made a useful Q&A-pair. If the former was negligible, or the latter is prohibitive, just removing the mess might be the best way forward anyway...

Comment: I like the sentiment, but I just don't think it will do hardly anything to the problem users and will annoy users who are trying to self-delete for valid reasons.

Comment: @Ajean There aren't many valid reasons for self-deletion in the first place. Users are already prompted with an "Are you sure?" modal when deleting their question; this kind of thing would simply expand it by adding a somewhat heavy-handed exit poll.

Comment: Except, as in other answers, self-deletion of bad questions is a GOOD thing. It keeps the system clear of them. Adding a roadblock will just leave cruft in the system, as laziness beats out the tiny modicum of responsibility askers feel.

Comment: @ABMagil I think the delete votes that users already have and utilize, in addition to the automated process that deletes bad/closed questions after a certain period, is more than enough to counter any addition to the amount of bad questions left undeleted because a *radio button list* was added to the *already existing* confirmation/warning modal.

Comment: #4: It was homework and I don't want my teacher to find this

Answer (score 20):

What about not being able to delete a question unless there is at least one-close vote against it? It means there is at least external validation from another party that the question does not belong on the site.

Comment: this seems like a good idea. I'd add *"for low rep users"* though.

Comment: Make that close-vote or down-vote, at a minimum. Whether to also include flags in the used signal, I'm not sure, maybe.

Comment: @Deduplicator you can have good answers to bad questions or people will down vote because the asker showed no effort, but the answerer did so down-vote is _not_ a good criterion.

Comment: @Deduplicator Unsure it is a good example or not, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870289/r-sample-from-sequence-stepwise-vs-replicate-with-different-results/35871435#35871435) I answered is not really good (unclear at first glance) but maybe my answer is not good either... I hope it is good enough to support ArtB point of view :)

Answer (score 8):

I think it disappointing when I see a question that someone has answered, gets deleted.

I would suggest that perhaps we need to remove 'self deletion':

- If the question is upvoted.
- If there is an answer, that hasn't been downvoted. (if feasible, also ignoring downvotes from the supplicant here).

And let the question be handled by the delete/vote-to-close mechanism, allowing the supplicant to cast these (regardless of rep) on their own question.

Because I do think it's a shame that someone can have an otherwise perfectly valid answer that they've offered, deleted without their consent. After all - the point of Stack Overflow isn't really to supply answers to particular individuals. It's to collate answers to questions for future reference.

Comment: To be clear to readers who might not be aware, it's already not possible for a user to delete their question if there is a positive-score answer. This answer is suggesting a slightly more-restrictive form of that measure.

Answer (score 5):

Deletion of questions along with their answers can be a pain, but that's most certainly not the universal behavior of low-rep users. A blanket avoidance policy is overkill.

I also used to avoid questions from low-rep users, not because of deletion but because I can't count on new users to formulate their requirements clearly, and to choose and upvote the good answers. But ironically, I only did this back when my reputation was low enough that I cared about unlocking useful privileges.

When I read SO and answer questions, it is primarily to learn about things I didn't know about before, or to improve my skills with things I did know about. Secondarily it is to help people who haven't actively put me off helping, but this describes the great majority of SO users at *any* rep level. **Now that I don't need the internet points, I'm happy to tackle any question that tickles my curiosity.**

Comment: But if there is the danger that the user takes your answer and immediately deletes the question that tickled your curiosity - would you like that? The feature mentioned in the last paragraph of Robert Harvey's answer (a minimal time period where the OP cannot delete their own questions) is probably still a good idea.

Comment: It's happened to me on occasion, though by no means often. I don't like it much, but it's no big deal unless I've invested a lot of effort in answering (which is rare for questions in this category).  My point being that it's not such a big deal that restricting deletion by new users is *necessary.* (Restrictions might still be useful, if done right.)