# Owner deletes his own question when he's got his answer

Tags: support, deleted-questions

20 minutes ago, a user asked a question about [twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twig) comparison on a [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) project. That was an easy question, but the solution is not an evident one, especially for [twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twig) beginners.

Two users, ChuckNorris and I provided some help. I edited the question, ChuckNorris and I provided some comments and an answer. When user has understood the answer, he simply deletes his post. My opinion is that this question could be useful for community. If each asker deletes its own question, Stack Overflow will no longer exist.

I know that student wants to delete things to cover up their cheating, but I don't think this is the case, here.

I understood that I can't vote for an undelete question. Only 20k+ users can vote to undelete and I am agree with SO rules.

I read in this [Meta Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316117/what-to-do-when-a-question-you-answered-gets-deleted-intentionally) that 
I could hold of a mod normally by flagging one of the OP's posts, but since we don't have any visible to it...

Is there a way to alert mods for deleted question?

Comment: Whatever the reason if a user repeatedly deletes his question which are answered it will result in asking ban.

Comment: This kind of behaviour will result in a ban.

Comment: Deleting questions *with answers* counts heavier towards a [post-ban] than deleting questions which don't.

Comment: Yes okay, but this question is not about whether the user gets banned or not but what to do to get the deleted question undeleted :)

Comment: Well, we'd need a link to vote to undelete :)

Comment: I thought you couldn't delete questions that had **actual answers**.

Comment: @Paulie_D if there's only one answer, and it doesn't have a positive score and isn't accepted, you can still delete a question.

Comment: Ahhh...thank you, Perhaps [What to do when a question you answered gets deleted intentionally?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316118/2802040)

Comment: @Paulie_D : This is the question I linked in my question. :-) I'm searching a way to alert mods. I'm agree with Glorfindel, a link to vote to undelete could be a solution. User who answered (and with a reputation score to determine) should be able to read the deleted topic and alert mod or vote to undelete.

Comment: If you want to alert a moderator, raise a custom flag. Or, I suppose you could just wait until one of them sees this question. It is not clear what you want, though, so they probably won't react appropriately. Are you wanting them to undelete the question? If so, ask for that.

Comment: @CodyGray :I'm sorry, I am not clear, and not very fluent in english. I didn't want to undelete *this* question. But you're right, my question is still a duplicate. Sorry.

Comment: Is this post which you are informing us about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545331/variable-equality-in-twig

Comment: Yes, it is. (But I am not asking to undelete it. I am trying to learn how to help community and moderators.)