# What happened to this question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I helped answer this question and followed up with OP. I found it deleted after going to sleep. Why was it deleted?

[Flask upload file to produce curve in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470337/flask-upload-file-to-produce-curve-in-python/42472417)

Comment: OP deleted the question himself.

Comment: @Rizier123 Wow. Why would he do such a selfish thing?

Comment: Related: [What to do when a question you answered gets deleted intentionally?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316117/what-to-do-when-a-question-you-answered-gets-deleted-intentionally)

Comment: That is something I can't tell you and only OP can.

Comment: @Rizier123 Do you think the question was an obvious bait from a help vampire? I used to avoid them well enough.

Comment: The question is now undeleted

Comment: ... and your answer is now upvoted, so they can't delete it again.