# Why am I not allowed to vote to delete or undelete another user's post more than once? [Obsolete]

Tags: support, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete, rules

> **Moderator note:** The Stack Exchange software [will no longer permit multiple delete or undelete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371277) as of Oct 26, 2021. This rule is now officially obsolete under these changes.

A question or answer I liked/disliked was deleted/undeleted. I disagreed with this, so, having [the moderator tools privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and/or being a [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), I voted to delete/undelete. That action was later reversed by another group of users with the same privileges, a moderator, or the Community user. The system did not prevent me from voting to put it back the way I think it should be, so I voted again.

I have now been informed by a diamond moderator (♦︎) that this is not allowed. Why am I not allowed to cast votes as I see fit?

I may have been doing this for a while, but was never previously told that it wasn't allowed. Is this a policy change?

> **Moderator note** - Please do not discuss this policy in this post. Please comment/post on the [broader community discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407860/rule-proposal-one-delete-undelete-per-post)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There was an [extensive community discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407860/rule-proposal-one-delete-undelete-per-post) after some contentious Meta Stack Overflow posts were made, where groups of voters were repeatedly clashing over this issue, casting delete and undelete votes over and over to put posts in the state they saw fit. These delete/undelete wars often led to frustration on both sides, resulting in moderators having to be called in to resolve the issue.

The problem for moderators has been that:

1. We had to ascertain if the closure and/or deletion was correct. For some subjects (especially when it was closed as a duplicate), this was not something moderators could adjudicate.
2. *Close votes* that result in closure are limited by the system to one per user per post (as are reopen votes), so disagreement over the closure state of a question tends to work itself out.
3. There is no corresponding system-enforced limit for delete or undelete votes (there are proposals on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vote-to-delete) to that end).
4. Previously, there has been no community rule against chain voting to delete or undelete a post.

#### [The rule moderators crafted to help resolve these disputes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407860/rule-proposal-one-delete-undelete-per-post) is:

1. No user may vote to delete a post more than once, or vote to undelete a post more than once.
2. This rule does not apply to the post author deleting or undeleting their own post.  (Note: deleting your own question with answers from other users [may still run afoul of other rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316118), and there *are* [system-enforced limitations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) as to when an author can delete their own post.)
3. Delete votes cast as actions for a review in any of the review queues do not count for the purposes of this rule. (One can verify that a vote was cast from the review queues through the review history in the post's timeline. This is to ensure this rule doesn't discourage people from reviewing.)
4. Votes which were cleared by the system and didn't contribute to the post being deleted or undeleted do not count for this rule. (As an example, this includes delete votes on questions that were [reopened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353607/how-do-i-vote-against-pending-delete-votes/353613#353613).)
5. This rule does not apply to diamond moderators (♦).

Violations of this rule are treated by moderators similarly to violations of other site rules. This rule is not enforced by the system, and moderators are not automatically made aware of infractions of this rule, so please raise a moderator flag if you see this rule being violated.

If you strongly disagree with a post being deleted or undeleted and you've already used your delete or undelete vote on that post, please start a discussion here on Meta Stack Overflow (if one hasn't already been started), or participate in an already existing discussion.