# Is it okay for somebody to reopen duplicate questions regularly?

Tags: discussion, users, dupehammer

Recently, I found that an active user in one of the tags I visit, dup-hammers questions in a peculiar way. The person mostly closes questions as duplicate when others answer them. Those questions are duplicates (and I believe almost 60-70% (or more) of the questions asked in that tag are in some way duplicates).

But many of the questions that this person answers are *also* duplicates (i.e. were answered at least 100 or more times in the tag)
(such as reshaping from long to wide or vice-versa or changing the names etc.).

The disturbing fact is that if I spent my time to find a dup-target and close the question, the next day, he reopens it. Answering those duplicate questions is okay and if the person fails to close as duplicate, it could be that they forgot to check for duplicates (although, I found the same question closed as duplicate by that person within 15-20 minutes when somebody else answered it and then he answered a similar one instead of closing it).

I understand that this is related to rep points - i.e. if the question gets closed as duplicate, there is a likelihood of getting downvotes instead of upvotes.

Is there any solution to this or is this based on user rep points?

**Update - Aug 29 2021**

Based on the responses so far, let me try to summarise.  The question generally asked in the comments are

1. Who is the user mentioned in the post?

My initial intention with this post was not to name somebody.  I was just seeking some confirmation as to what one should do when somebody reopens dupehammered questions repeatedly.  Some comments below suggested to flag (which I did many times and got rejected).  These reopening incidents were not based on 7 years history.  It is just something happening in the last few months (around 15-20 dupes hammered getting reopened with no explanation.  These are very basic questions asked almost on a daily basis and these are the same questions the same user dupe hammer when others answer).  Regarding the identity of the person, it is already revealed by another user in the comments with the links as well.

2. You also reopened questions and why blame somebody?

I admit that I also reopened questions in the past.  I am an active user in SO for more than 7 years and I do admit that I am not the perfect person as many of those commenters.  I got a warning message from SO on August 2020 and from that time onwards my reopening activity is reduced (even when somebody dupe hammered with wrong links, I didn't reopen). In the answer posted by
@AndrasDeak, the statistics used may be from the entire history and I believe it just diverts the question.   Now, lets consider this - even if it is all true i.e. I reopen questions regularly, can't I report the behavior of another person.

Another general behavior I notice is whenever a high rep user makes a post, it diverts the question and its essence i.e. people are making turns to blame the high rep user.  It was seen many times before.  This year itself I had seen another high rep user publicly humiliated for reopening a question or two. Imagine if this was posted by a low rep user against a high rep user, the general reaction will be all positive.  If these are responses, people don't post on meta.

Comment: it sounds like you're describing what you see as a malicious use, or, at the very least, an inconsistent application of the rules by a particular user in a way that favors their own reputation gains. While we can discuss this here, and how rules should be applied equally regardless of whether or not you benefit from the action, it doesn't do anything to help your particular case. If you think a user is abusing their privileges, a mod flag is the appropriate course of action.

Comment: @KevinB I did mod flag and even reached out to SO, but the advise I got is to post on `meta`.

Comment: Mortals can't catch these exceptions @akrun.

Comment: Also, when i flag, it gets rejected because of some constraint that flags are not meant to discuss about dupe tags

Comment: He regularly dupe tags posts that I answer and it is a valid dupe as well and I don't usually reopen.  But, with more than 15 or so reopening by the same user (even very simple questions) makes me wonder whether it is to avoid getting downvotes.  I get downvoted regularly when there is a dupe tagged

Comment: @41686d6564 I meant questions that are possible duplicate to the question asked (and tagged as dupe)

Comment: I'm confused. AFAIK, there's no such thing called "tagged as dupe". You probably mean "closed as duplicate". I think it's better to stick to the terms that are recognized by most users to make sure your post is understandable (unless I'm the one who's missing something here; in which case, I apologize).

Comment: @41686d6564 sorry, I meant as "closed as duplicate"

Comment: @akrun I've edited the question and tried to reword it to the best of my ability to make it clearer. Please feel free to roll back or edit it further if I messed something up.

Comment: @41686d6564 thank you for that.  I am not a native english speaker, thus it may have some grammatical errors.  Sorry!

Comment: you must provide some links that you flagged, else we can't see the history

Comment: @nbk flagging gets rejected with `declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it`  Almost similar kind of messages

Comment: @akrun then provide the flagged and decline links and we will see, so we only know your interpretation. When i have a question open and some one closes it as dupe or something else i can still answer it.

Comment: i got now more than once a low quality answer which has a sentence and a link. what will you do mods are mods and only human after all

Comment: @nbk can i give links in private

Comment: Demonstrating abuse of the hammer privilege requires a substantial amount of evidence, of which you've provided none. If a mod has advised you to post on meta, they probably don't think your points are worthless, but also that they're not conclusive enough to take action on unilaterally. They presumably expect that details of the user's activities are going to be shared publicly, otherwise the community can do nothing expect say "sure, abuse is bad, raise a flag", which you've already done. To get proper feedback, I'd suggest demonstrating a clear pattern of the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @akrun you can post them in your question and post all got

Comment: @cigien Wouldn't this be then targeting a person

Comment: @nbk If that is done, then wouldn't that cause a lot of reaction from meta?  The person contributes by answering and I don't want the person to be vilified in public. I only posted in meta to show that there are some kind of activities happening in the tag which is kind of abuse of gold tag

Comment: It would be targeting a user, but that is not *per se* disallowed. It's certainly frowned upon, and the appropriate thing to do first is always to raise a mod flag. However, once the mod flag is declined with advice to post on meta, that to me is permission to discuss the issue publicly. And now that you have posted this meta, the cat is pretty much out of the bag. You can only be describing a handful of users, and users will speculate which one you're referring to, and that's not helpful to anyone. I would suggest being explicit about the problem. Make sure to do it politely, of course.

Comment: I was thinking about the kind of nastiness against a very high rep user (when they reopened one question)

Comment: Let me hazard a guess about the tag involved - it is [tag:regex] again, isn't it?

Comment: We should explicitly declare all regex questions as "not programming" and therefore off-topic. :-)

Comment: @Oleg No, the tag is [tag:r] and the user is Ronak Shah.

Comment: And here are the evidence [1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61570710/timeline), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68645348/timeline), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68617046/timeline), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68572228/timeline), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68539068/timeline), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68544998/timeline), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68538318/timeline), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68523201/timeline), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68454030/timeline), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68372348/timeline).

Comment: @oguzismail ah, I see, thanks for the correction and direct links :) [tag:r] was my second on the list of guesses

Comment: @AndrasDeak - I don't see how it's "funny". If one frequents SO enough, and sticks to specific tags, one can see alleged misbehavior when it pops up. In that case, it is something "about akrun" that sees them pulled in to this, but it's nothing sinister. Why are you throwing shade at them anyway?

Comment: @StoryTeller of course, it's not funny. What's really going on is that there are a few very-high-rep answerers-of-everything who sometimes step on one another's toes during their habitual answering of low-quality posts and blatant dupes. Sometimes one wants to answer the dupe and the other closes it. The next time it's the other way around. It's "funny".

Comment: @AndrasDeak - None of this is of any substance. Even if akrun is behaving egregiously, their claims [have some merit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411068/is-it-okay-for-somebody-to-reopen-duplicate-questions-regularly?noredirect=1#comment862782_411068). And that merit is [not diminished by the origin](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/genetic). Any other discussion of akrun serves no purpose other than to inflame and cause strife.

Comment: @StoryTeller agreed. The "funny" part is that both sides in these little feuds can pretend to be locally right, because there's always another side that objectively does something wrong. Probably the same psychology as long-standing geopolitical conflicts.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - Ah yes, ignoring my point and plowing on with the fallacy in hand. Seems you are guilty of drama inducing behavior yourself. It isn't on topic here, despite your emotional investment and dislike of those "very high rep users".

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica More than *some*. [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1373433/test) returns 50+ such questions.

Comment: @oguzismail lovely query! If I [reverse the user IDs I get 77](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1453818/test). What does that mean?

Comment: @oguzismail  What you are saying is from my entire history in SO.  I was contacted by SO and given warnings for that.  After that I rarely do that.  O are you saying tha we cannot correct our behavior?

Comment: @AndrasDeak why bring up somebody else into this question where they have no role in it.  Or are you saying that only `perfect` persons can post in `meta`?  Are you that `perfect` guy? Regarding the disagreements, it happens only when there is a clear violation.  It is all documented in another meta post and I am not the only person who answered on that meta.  Also, the question was not asked by me.  I rarely do post in meta and the only question i asked in meta before this is not related to any feud

Comment: @akrun when did your behaviour change thanks to SO contacting you? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68599120/timeline) was reopened by you two minutes after it was closed ten minutes after you answered it. This happened July 31 (2021).

Comment: @AndrasDeak You are just cherrypicking something. I would say look for the number of ones reopened instead of cherrypicking one and blaming.

Comment: Consider this scenario.  The guy hammers a lot of the ones I answer.  I get downvote.  When I close his obvious dupes, it gets reopened.  I might have opened a couple of ones.  Are you trying to defend the behavior by saying that you are not perfect so stop reporting?

Comment: No, akrun, you did well to report him and yourself. I didn't even downvote this question of yours. I'm merely telling you to do better.

Comment: @akrun Just being objective, not implying anything.

Comment: What exactly is this meta question asking? If you already got contacted for the same misbehaviour, you should know that it's not okay. If you are asking about the specific user, not mentioning the specific user seems to make the question pointless.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Have you read the comments?  It is already revealed by oguzismail and also in one of the answers.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I know that it is not okay and I was following the instruction as per the email.  But, if somebody does the same behavior, what is the solution?  Do you have anything to offer or just blaming the whistleblower.

Comment: @akrun Please try and take these comments as feedback *on the meta question*, not yourself. Without knowing anything about you, *the question's appearance* raises lots of red flags. If these are unintentional (and I assume they are), please take it as an opportunity to realise this and remove them. The question *still* does not ask "if somebody does the same behavior, what is the solution?" – instead it brings up the issue of rep, it blames a specific user just waiting to be revealed, it focuses on how *you* are wronged.

Comment: There are some helpful SEDE queries: "[Dupe Hammer accuracy](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1370822/dupe-hammer-accuracy)" (HammerClosed Reopened Reclosed PctError), "[Close stats for top dup-hammer users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1417690/close-stats-for-top-dup-hammer-users)" (HammerClosed Reopened PctError), needs some optimization and column sorting "[Dupehammered questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1360786/dupehammered-questions)", [continued]

Comment: "[Dupe Hammer usage per User](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1350004/dupe-hammer-usage-per-user)", "[Close stats for top dup-hammer users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1308794/close-stats-for-top-dup-hammer-users)" --- As you can see neither is the greatest *offender* (decision reversed, and remains that way), but one is reversed more than the other. --- Just search SEDE for "Hammer" to find more.

Comment: Agreed that mods are not subject matter experts and mods cannot judge every dupe dispute but it would be better if we directly address the bahvior OP is pointing at rather than digging up historical data that OP himself is acknowledging. We don't expect mods to be SMEs but at least they should appear fair and impartial in expecting and asking for certain behaviors from contributors.

Comment: I actually have noticed similar, if not same behavior with a few high-rep users in the css tag as well. Bringing it up would just turn it into an argument on semantics and vague rule interpretation so I ended up un-watching the tag. I rarely interact with css tagged questions now so I don't know if it's still going on or not though.

Comment: "I know that it is not okay and I was following the instruction as per the email. But, if somebody does the same behavior, what is the solution?" I think this is a very important and good comment. It should be in the main question, and the question should have been "How to handle users who reopen duplicate questions regularly?", and we would all have a better day handling this question, I believe.

Comment: I've noticed the same behaviour in the [tag:regex] tag. If you lurk there, you know who I'm talking about

Comment: @Paolo It is going on forever.  There are multiple meta posts regarding regex.  I think the person/persons who does this wants to discourage people from posting on regex i.e. suppose 5 to 10 questions you answered in `regex` gets deleted, you will think twice or thrice to even post on regex as -1) it is waste of your time, 2) mental stress ...

Comment: @akrun Yes, exactly! I'm glad I'm not the only one who noticed this

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-should-we-do-when-one-person-tries-to-delete-every-duplicate

Comment: I must have read over 10 different comments for a specific pattern of behaviour demonstrated by the same user in the `regex` tag. Why aren't moderators doing anything about this?

Comment: @Paolo If they do the deletion for the sole intention of curation, I can understand.  But, that is not the case because they reopen questions that are obvious duplicates because they answer it.

Comment: So, have you folks mod-flagged the suspected misbehavior lately? What happened with the flags? It might seem obvious to you that there is misbehavior in the regex tag, yet the repeated, thinly veiled criticism of specific people here on Meta also paints a picture of quite another possible misbehavior.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I was just responding to a comment from Paolo.  I didn't name anybody.  It is the link Paolo brought up.  I guess even talking about that misbehavior is termed as misbehavior?

Comment: @akrun What irks *me personally* is that even though nobody names anybody, and nobody actually proves anything, many people still act like a *specific* somebody *definitely* did it. Is that a misbehaviour? *Possibly*. It's *definitely* not a situation that invites open discussion...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. `nobody actually proves anything`. hmm.  How many links you wanted or how many meta posts with clear links.  If you look at the link that Paolo showed, there is ample evidence (if only you want to look into it). Even, I witnessed it multiple times about their behavior.  It is just that some people doesn't want others to post in `regex` tag and it is quite obvious.

Answer (score 69):

We had an interesting discussion in comments that deserves to be pulled into an answer.

oguz ismail pulled up [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1373433/test) that searches for posts that were dupe closed by you and unhammered by the other user. There's a shocking 67 cases of these happening!

So I [reversed the user IDs in the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1453818/test). There's a shocking 77 cases of these happening! I looked at 3 random questions in the list, and you reopened all of them on the same day or the following day.

---

The bottom line will always be that reopening legitimate dupes is bad. Answering dupes is also bad! Answering low-quality questions is also bad! How about we (and by we I mean we all, including you) stop doing all of this, and drop the hypocrisy when others indulge in the same harmful behaviour?

Comment: I would also point out that this 'feud' has been brought up on several occasions before, in chat. One such occasion, in [The Ministry of Silly Hats](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51455647#51455647), elicited this fine comment from yourself: *When you have two power-users in a petty war they are invariably both wrong.*

Comment: @AdrianMole These are all from history.  Are you suggesting that he reopens everything and is fine because I reopened some questions in the past.

Comment: @akrun No. I'm suggesting (as is Andras, I think) that you are both wrong (as are all/any others who habitually either answer or reopen obvious duplicates). In so doing, you are converting yourself from a **great asset** on Stack Overflow into a *liability* and an embarrassment.

Comment: @akrun you keep inisting that this is history so I'll have to keep digging up obvious evidence to the contrary. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1453835) lists posts that were unhammered by yourself. I looked at the top 5 and most if not all were closed after you answered, and then unhammered by yourself. The newest one in that list was unhammered by you less than two weeks ago, only 2 minutes after it was closed. Looking at these posts suggests that user [Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851712) could write this meta post _about you_ and they'd be right.

Comment: @AndrasDeak That was because there was a dupe targeting i.e. his answers clear dupes were not hammered and if tagged, gets reopened whereas mine is getting tagged and then downvoted.  So, I might have reopened some out of this obvious hypocrisy

Comment: @akrun So, rather than revenge *downvoting*, you're engaging in revenge *reopening*?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Also, you are just saying that if a dupe is hammered it should be a dupe.  The guy closes a dupe with 3 or 4 questions (to make as a dupe i.e. question addressing one thing in a past, second in another post ) and when this was closed, it becomes a dupe.

Comment: @AdrianMole ok, now we are in a territory where you are accusing somebody because I posted a behavior

Comment: @AdrianMole What do you call the other persons behavior of reopening ?

Comment: Well, if I were a moderator (and many here are likely very glad that I am not), I would be seriously considering "imposed vacations" for the pair of you. I'd probably set you both a pile of homework to do, as well.

Comment: I recommend that the both of you continue bickering in chat where I don't get notifications.

Comment: @AdrianMole You are again going back to history.  This was addressed to SO.  Let's look for something happening in the future rather than the behavior already addressed by SO with warnings

Comment: @akrun When was the most recent SO warning? I think there's some confusion between you and AndrasDeak/AdrianMole about that.

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoriaReinstateCMs if you are asking about the last mail reply from SO, it is on 12/8/2021/. The specific warning about the reopening was on 20/8/2020

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoriaReinstateCMs if that query is ordered by date (based on what I checked) then probably 4 or 5 reopened after the 20/8/2020.  It may be interesting to check how many were reoopened by the other person in the same time period

Comment: I don't mean to pile on the bandwagon. But, as an outside observer without any context: if there have been 4 or 5 instances since the last warning, I think it's unfair to say that @AdrianMole is "going back to history."

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoriaReinstateCMs Are you saying that absolutely nothing should be reopened even if it doesn't suit as a dupe.  Then, nobody should reopen any questions hammered even if that is not a correct one.  What I meant to say is that in the answer, it is quoting that 77 reopened which goes back to history.  Of course for a high rep user to get bashed even half reopened is enough compared to 20 or more reopened by the other person

Comment: @akrun Oh, I see—if those 4 or 5 reopenings are all legitimate (I haven't looked at them myself, so I can't say they're not), please ignore my comment. (With that said, I honestly don't think "the other person"'s behavior is at all relevant here.)

Comment: "The bottom line will always be that reopening legitimate dupes is bad." That should be written in bold and on top and bottom.

Answer (score 38):

I'm going to pick on akrun for a moment, since akrun asked this. **By no means should anyone assume akrun is alone in this behavior.** I simply have a ready example here involving him, and it really typifies *the whole problem*.

I'll start with [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66211686/grep-a-string-with-multiple-slash-keys). It's one of the messes that helped prompt the [delete rule change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407953/2370483). akrun voted to reopen it in the middle and answer it. He then gives [the same answer as the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29114021/2370483). I generally don't weigh in on dupe disputes, but this one was fairly obvious. The question *should have been left as a duplicate*. That's why I have a hard time buying

> But many of the questions that this person answers are also duplicates (i.e. were answered at least 100 or more times in the tag) (such as reshaping from long to wide or vice-versa or changing the names etc.).

akrun later commented

> Once I got moderator warning when I reopened some questions in the past. I was thinking that the same criteria applies to everyone

There's a lot of moving parts here, but the biggest ones are

1. We don't have moderators who are experts in every tag. We can kinda field SME flags for [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), but unless it's blatant (like above) we can't really resolve **duplicate disputes based on content**. We have no diamond users who are experts in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) (like a lot of tags).
2. There's lots of hypocrisy from all sides. There are several users who feel that their closures or reopens should not be questioned. If they closed it, it was a legit dupe and the other user was targeting them just out of spite. If they opened it and answered it, well, it wasn't the same thing as the dupe.

We can (and do) moderate blatant abuses. I've warned a user who abused their hammer to nullify close votes. And if there's a broader pattern, we do sometimes deal with them (we have to involve community managers in those cases because we can't see votes). But beyond that **moderators really can't resolve disputes over duplicate content**. The system doesn't allow you to successfully close or reopen more than once, so we typically just let it sort itself out.

> Recently, I found that an active user in one of the tags I visit, dup-hammers questions in a peculiar way. The person mostly closes questions as duplicate when others answer them. Those questions are duplicates (and I believe almost 60-70% (or more) of the questions asked in that tag are in some way duplicates).

The problem here is

1. You're *highly* active in several tags. You bump up against other gold badges *all the time*
2. Your flags are overly simple (this is an actual mod flag)

   > This person is trying to dupe only when I answer a question. He is so biased that he reopens even questions I dupe tag
3. You're engaging in the same behavior you decry

From where mods sit, it looks like a simple content dispute. As such, we've suggested you take those *specific question* disputes to Meta, where the broader community can evaluate if there is indeed a valid point about the duplicate closures or reopens. And when you add hypocrisy in, it starts to look like "I really just don't like this user because they disagree with me". Those flags are highly unlikely to be sustained.

The main thing is no patterns have been established of any user targeting duplicates (or users), let alone that those actions were unwarranted. If you're going to flag activity like this, you need a clear trail for moderators to follow. That's where you need to start if you want help in this area. We're willing to help, but only if you help us first and are not an active participant in the problem.

## TL;DR How can I deal with this then?

1. Remember that moderators are not subject matter experts. Use Meta to discuss and help settle **duplicate subject content disputes**. This includes

   - Reopening a duplicate
   - Posting an answer that is the same as the duplicate (it's rare when it's clear to folks outside the subject at hand)
   - Wrong duplicate targets
2. Mod flag anything where the use of dupehammers is **obviously abusive**. We define abuse as using your hammer to deliberately harass other users or subvert the close/reopen process. If you're claiming a pattern, please note the questions involved in one flag for clarity (flagging each question separately may not get seen by the same moderators). Please note that reopening a question to answer is not abusive and hard to prove by itself without Meta backup.
3. For anything else, use Meta to establish a pattern of bad behavior involving the subject matter itself. Once you have a few Meta discussions about specific problems that support your position, then mod flag with links to said Metas and we can then deal with the user directly.

Comment: This is the same question for which I got a moderator warning. I don't know why you are bringing this past behavior when the question itself is for another user's behavior

Comment: None of the answers here is kind of addressing the behavior of the other persons' behavior.  The essence here is that "ok you have done similar things in the post, now you shut up!"

Comment: @akrun Seriously? **You are doing the same exact thing**. You then act shocked whenever we point that out to you. Again, this isn't just about you. I could list upward of a dozen users who act the same way. But as long as this remains a problem about "other users" alone, nothing will change. We want all the dupehammer warring to stop. The only alternative we have is to suspend everyone who does this which (again) is a list that includes your own behavior. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Your comment `If they closed it, it was a legit dupe and the other user was targeting them just out of spite.`.  If you check `reshaping from long to wide` or `wide to long`, almost daily these questions are asked.  If the user I specified dupe tags others and then answers it, it is a violation

Comment: After I got the SO warning, as I specified that my reopening frequency is very low compared to the other person.  This also imply that they can even dupehammer wrong ones when I answer, I get downvoted and I don't complain.  But, they answer dupes, when it is closed, reopen.  Is there a solution for that or not?

Comment: It is kind of disappointing that when a question is asked, it is just diverted to the askers history

Comment: It is more than what you think.  There is an chat group in SO, which does target voting or dupe hammering.  The person mentioned in this post had even stated the best time to downvote is just before the daily close time so that I couldn't make up.  How do I know?  I happened to visit that chat room accidentally and found comments against me

Comment: @akrun What chat room? Can you share a link to it?

Comment: @oguzismail the one I commented was what I saw some years back.  They now delete all chat transcripts (if it is against a person)

Comment: Another accusation you can't support with evidence then. Oy.

Comment: @oguzismail well, you already dig up some links and the person which I didn't specified and proved to be correct, right?

Comment: Just because akrun did the same thing doesn't make this meta question invalid. This answer isn't really actionable and it's just putting the OP in a spotlight.

Comment: I think Machavity explains the issue pretty succinctly @rene. It's a dupe-hammer war that's spilt over into meta, what is it you expect them to do?

Comment: @user692942 Assuming it is a dupehammer war and I am the only person warned by SO not to reopen question while the other person can reopen without any reaction.  Is that a fair case?  (Lets forget all the history of 66 vs 77 - I don't even understand what is the point of that comparison.  Is that to suggest that only when he crosses 77 there is a any merit in the claim?)

Comment: @akrun the problem is, it's been proven that very recently you have participated in the same behaviour you are now crying about on meta. If you expect to be taken seriously by the mods and the wider community first stop participating in the same behaviour then (when enough time has passed) come back to meta. You feel bad because you've been pulled up for it and you feel others are getting away with it, but, how do you know they also haven't been pulled up by the moderators? The simple answer, you don't.

Comment: @user692942 none of the comments are addressing the question.  It is going back to my history or what i have done or reopened.  My point is that there is a higher frequency of reopening by that person in the last few months whereas I reopened very few as I was warned by the SO.  It is beyond my reasoning that when we report an incident about another person, the question is getting diverted to ask whether the asker is perfect or not.

Comment: @user692942 If the moderators had pulled up that person and warned, this kind of repeated behavior wouldn't happen.  i.e. reopening 2 questions two days back (which are clear dupes)

Comment: @akrun I think I finally understand why the mods told you to post here.

Comment: Is reopen hammering your own question that was closed as a duplicate by others considered obviously abusive?

Comment: @Machavity I wonder, wouldn't it be far more effective to suspend both users involved instead of posting a long answer that boils down to *I don't know how to resolve this* and letting this sort itself out (which appears unlikely to happen anytime soon)? I mean, what are you waiting for? It's obvious that both parties are abusing their privileges in order to 'win'?

Comment: *We have no diamond users who are experts in r (like a lot of tags).*  - [yes you do](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3093387/josliber) - though it's irrelevant to the discussion :)

Comment: @gparyani it's only abusive if the question is a duplicate. Reopening a question that should not be closed is idiomatic use of the privilege. But let's face it; in these feuds the questions are almost always duplicates.

Comment: @oguzismail I think sometimes it's easy to assume that the mod team knows how to handle *everything*. Usually there's a neutral rule to apply and side-step the thorny content issues. Dupe disputes rarely have such a clear-cut solution. Suspending them both is an extreme solution because all you're doing is making both sides "lose", which means now they agree to be mad at mods instead of each other (which means angry Meta posts, CM appeals, etc.) That's not a workable solution. The system more or less sorts the problem by limiting how many times you can vote. That's the best we have to offer

Comment: @DavidArenburg Fair enough, but he's been on hiatus for a while (real life for some mods has been crazy). If you're waiting for a specific mod to come resolve your content dispute, you might be waiting a very long time...

Comment: @gparyani Not necessarily (the system allows you to reopen vote your own question in any context so clearly it's not considered inherently abusive). If you have a long string of reopening your own questions, that could be mod flagged for investigation (see TL;DR #2)

Comment: No, no content disputes here. What we have here is two high-reputation users closing and reopening questions with the intent of bringing harm to one another, nothing else.

Comment: as I said- it's irrelevant to the discussion. As one of many gold badges who were involved in closing/reopening wars with akrun over the years on the [tag:r]- I fully agree with you. This post is full of hypocrisy and whining of a person that for years was constantly answering and reopening dupes. He only found it disturbing when he finally found his match. And, for the record, we all answered dupes during our SO careers, but we didn't systematically reopen them once they were closed, and most importantly, we learned to not answer them anymore- unlike the OP and his new counterpart.

Comment: I don't know how long this is going on, but if it's going on for longer already, couldn't moderators hand out a bit of timeouts for everyone involved in abusive behavior regarding opening and closures?

Comment: @Trilarion Here you are assuming that all the reopening are unfair.  Some of them are opened because of wrongly hammered.

Comment: I agree with the spirit of the answer, but I guess it would have been received better had it been written like this: "The q as is feels more like a personal rant than a general discussion, but to keep things objective, I will answer the discussion part and ignore the rant. The answer is: "No, it's not okay to reopen duplicate questions regularly" because <reason>. So we need this to stop. I ran a SEDE query as a potential indicator of users who might be involved in these behavior and here is the list of users. To OP, notice that you are also on this list, so please revise your behavior too."

Comment: @akrun Sorry for the misunderstanding. Wrongly closed duplicates would be rightly reopened of course and that happens. Have done that myself. I was here only speaking about abusive behavior, i.e. frequent reopening of questions that are closed and should remain closed. Of course it's difficult to be sure of that but there might be clear cases.

Comment: My suggested answer doesn't suggested that at all. In fact, I started with what to do before listing out the users.

Answer (score 8):

Flag the user's interactions with these posts for moderator attention.  They'd be able to put together a pattern of either abuse or misuse.

Admittedly, unless they were a gold badge user who could do this instantly, the abuse is limited to only the scope of whether two others decided to join in on this (which would still be flag-worthy if there's enough of a recurrence).

Comment: I flagged the users action, but I got the message to not flag, but to post on meta

Comment: You should be explicit; don't just say that they're closing a dupe but point to a history of dupe closures and suspicious behavior.

Comment: I sent the links at least 10 times flagged, but they gets rejected

Comment: Once I got moderator warning when I reopened some questions in the past.  I was thinking that the same criteria applies to everyone

Comment: @akrun Did you flag those reopened dupes individually? Or did you explain in the mod flag comment that the user has a pattern of reopening & answering dupes, with links to several examples?

Comment: @PM2Ring frankly, it's a bit hard to explain things properly with links in the number of characters one is given for mod flags. Not impossible, but not very easy.

Comment: @Oleg Fair point, but you can easily fit 3 or 4 short links ("share" links with your own user ID removed).

Comment: @PM2Ring true that. Just noted that it's a bit hard to get a well-formed custom mod message under current constraints - not impossible, though, true. We'd need to see what akrun sent to mods to determine if the info supplied was thorough enough.

Comment: @akrun flag this meta post and tell them that meta said to raise a flag, then when that gets rejected saying to make a meta post about that, make a meta flag meta flag post, saying that the flag reject said to make a meta post about a flag about a meta post about a flag. (I'm just being silly, please don't actually do that)

Comment: @jrh Its like Psaki says "circle back" i.e. if I flag, it gets rejected, if I contact SO, they say to post on meta.  if I post on meta, they say to flag it.  Then, make a background check on the person who posted.  Find out some instance where the person failed (according to their impeccable standards) and then calls names i.e. `embarrasment` etc.  It just feels that for a high rep person, reporting anything is not feasible

Comment: @akrun "I flagged the users action, but I got the message to not flag, but to post on meta ..." Meta is the place for consensus. Flagging is the way to get a quick cleanup. Probably this means that the mods weren't sure and wanted to get more opinions on that case.