# What should you do when you realize you have answered a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

I have a question about best current practices regarding a situation where one first answers a question and then later realizes the question is a duplicate.

As a concrete example, I answered a question this morning. I probably should have realized right from the start that the question is so basic that it *must* be a duplicate, but alas, I didn't, and I wrote an answer. (If I were to make any excuse, I had just gotten up and not had my morning brew yet.)

Shortly after me, someone else also posted an answer, which in turn refers the OP to an answer of a duplicate question. After reading this answer which essentially says the question is a duplicate, I used my gold badge dupe-hammer to close the question.

Now, the question is: is there anything else I should do? I feel like it would make sense to delete my answer in order to not spread answers across multiple questions. It looks like some of the information in my answer is not contained in any of the answers to the duplicate target, so I might repost it there after deleting it on the duplicate question.

Comment: it's fine to have duplicate questions with different answers BUT it's not fine if we already have a "million" duplicate questions of a very known and common issue. If it's the latter situation, I would vote to delete the question later (IMO)

Comment: IMO, available options include letting your answer as is / converting your answer to a CW / deleting it (like you did) / posting a new answer with the missing info on the original question / comment on an answer that was lacking the few bit of info so it may be added by the answerer. These options aren't necessarily exclusive and I really think which fits better depends on the situation. However when you posted your answer to the original question that would have been better to tailor it to said question. As it currently stands, it quotes the closed question, which makes it look weird.

Comment: "*As it currently stands, it quotes the closed question, which makes it look weird.*" Yes, exactly..., I had the same reaction, and went checking the Qt (where you (#OP) re-posted the Answer) twice to find out where this Quote was coming from and could only "understand" because of this Meta Post... // + @Kaiido, I don't know/understand what "CW" means in "*converting your answer to a CW*"...? // EDIT: => "Community Wiki" of course!, seen your Reply #MisterMiyagi...)

Comment: *so I might repost it there after deleting it on the duplicate question.* - you have all the powers to do this; it's what I'd do. Add a comment to the dupe even, calling the OP to your answer if it meets some need of theirs specifically

Comment: In your opinion, was the question and answer you provided better than the answer of the question you closed it a duplicate of? Theres a potential (rare) case to make the old question the duplicate of new one

Comment: Consider changing your answer to community wiki — then you can't (so easily) be accused of rep-whoring.  If I close a question as a duplicate, I usually add a comment detailing the application of the duplicate to the user's scenario.  But that's when I've not answered the question before closing as a duplicate.  Or consider deleting your answer — maybe converting it to a comment if it is short enough to be compressible.  But if the answer is substantial, it may be worth leaving it.

Comment: I've probably done this 100 times - sometimes you don't know for sure it's a duplicate, and it's easier to answer the question than to go looking. If it gets closed eventually I don't worry about it, maybe my answer added some new nuance that wasn't obvious before. Karma will be served eventually.

Comment: Just remember that we're all human, and assume good faith about ourselves and each other.

Comment: @MarkRansom  _"sometimes you don't know for sure it's a duplicate, and it's easier to answer the question than to go looking"_. Really? Occasionally it might be tricky to identify potential duplicates for some questions, but it general shouldn't everyone check for duplicates before posting an answer? It's really not that hard, and certainly takes less time/effort than posting an answer.

Comment: @skomisa the most common problem I find is just not knowing which search terms are going to be effective.

Comment: Related: [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](/q/252009/11107541)

Answer (score 45):

If your answer brings something new to the original Q&A you can *request a merge* of both questions.

(Keep in mind that your answer has to match the original question or it would be a mess.)

If it doesn't, well, it happens. Learn from it. Google before answering to find the duplicate link. I wouldn't blame you as it happened to me many times. If there aren't any upvotes yet, I usually delete my answer.

If it already has upvotes, don't delete it: I get upvotes from my old answers on duplicates frequently, just because the question is asked differently so search engines find it before the original one, so I figure it keeps helping people after all those years.

If you always put the quality of the site before your reputation points, you can't be wrong.

Comment: In this same vein [I have some general guidelines for merge requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400200/2370483) (they're mine alone but I think most of the mods would find it useful). Jean is hitting my point #4 here: your answer needs to be unique amongst the would-be target question's answers.

Comment: *If you always put the quality of the site before your reputation points, you can't be wrong.*  I would like to agree, because I try not to care about rep, but the ice may be thin here.  I had bookmarked [this earlier answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415621#415638) by @Machavity in which he writes "We frown upon gold badge holders answering questions and then closing them as a duplicate".  As it happens, several times I've done the same thing Jörg did, and I've wondered if it looked bad, and I've thought maybe I should delete my answer, to avoid the impression of rep-farming.

Comment: @SteveSummit Correct, that is what you should do. No harm no foul.

Comment: @SteveSummit there is a difference between "answer and instantly close to prevent others to answer" vs. "answer and close some time later after someone found good duplicate" - otherwise I'm 100% agree with the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate/286074#286074) you sort-of linked to.

Comment: If you want to show you do not care about points but think the answer on the duplicate has value and do not want to delete it then you can convert your answer to a community wiki.

Comment: community wiki is not for that. You don't get rep but the duplicate answer still clutters the site.

Comment: Merge request is kind of hard to get (because it involves moderators && it's irreversible etc.. What about just copy paste the answer to the target, then delete the source one instead?

Comment: if it has upvotes you're going to lose them. But in the other case, yes

Answer (score 35):

Answering a question and then closing it with your hammer looks bad.  Nobody else can answer the question because you locked them out.  Voters will only be able to choose from a single answer to the question - yours.  This creates appearances of using your gold badge in an unfair way to increase your reputation.

I'm not saying that that is that actual intent here, just that it creates the appearance of it. I've answered and then found duplicates on the Webmasters site where I moderate.  Other users called me out because it looks bad.

I would suggest that you:

- Try to find duplicates *before* answering to avoid this problem before creating it
- Don't use your dupe hammer, leaving your answer on a question. Instead do one of the following:

  - Let other people close the question rather than doing it yourself
  - Delete your answer (and add it to the duplicate question if it would add value there)
  - Request that the questions be merged (if the answers would work on the duplicate)
  - Make your answer a "Community wiki" so that votes on it don't affect your reputation

The same advice applies to a lesser degree for all users: Don't *vote to close* **and** *answer* the same question. Moderators and gold badge holders hold special privileges that makes such behavior especially problematic. But even for normal users, it doesn't look great to have voted to close a question for which you have an answer that could increase your reputation.

Comment: Last paragraph is pure gold.

Comment: I agree with all of this. Even voting to close when you have also answered looks bad; if you happen to have dupehammer powers, your vote to close _will_ close and you cannot prevent it, and now that looks _really_ bad. Just delete your answer and life is good.

Comment: @matt I know there's at least one time where I answered a question, then later realized it was a dupe.  So I voted to close, not realizing that I had a gold badge for that question  and hammered it by accident.

Comment: Nobody should be sanctioned for answering and closing if it only happens rarely. It's only abuse if you make it a regular habit.

Comment: @MarkRansom This is not relevant, perhaps, but I have often wished to shed my dupehammer powers so that I could _vote_ to close a question as a duplicate _without_ closing it on the spot. It's like a pull request: I'd like others to check my work.

Answer (score 9):

I think what this comes down to is the age-old adage: *With power comes responsibility*.  If you've got that gold badge, you've got to be really careful when you come across a great question that you're all juiced up to compose a scintillatingly good answer to.  But if it might be a dup, you've really got to slow down and consider that possibility first, lest your new, scintillatingly good answer turn into an albatross.

Full disclosure: I've done precisely what Jörg describes, several times.  Sometimes I didn't realize there was a dup, or forgot to check, or checked only superficially.  Sometimes I wanted to give the OP a tailored answer, while also permanently redirecting to the canonical dup for the full story.

But this always felt a little sketchy, and I've since learned that, indeed, [answering and then closing-as-dup is definitely frowned upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate/286074#286074), because of the selfish impression it gives.

In fact, I confess that once or twice, before I knew better, I did the seemingly-selfish thing, but with a twist: although I was definitely trying to shut out other answerers, it wasn't because I wanted all the rep points for myself.  (I truly didn't care.)  No, my thinking was just that I wanted to give the OP a high-quality, more tailored answer than I knew was available at the dup, *but* I wanted to head off all the low-quality or downright wrong answers I knew the question would otherwise attract.

But! I now know that was wrong, and I definitely don't do that any more, and I've settled on a compromise: If I really want to give the OP a "tailored answer", while also closing as a dup, I'll instead give that "tailored answer" *as a comment*, where it can't be construed as a troll for extra points.

It may be useful to illustrate this with an example.  Under the [c] tag, perhaps the most common question ever is variations on "I don't understand why the expression `i = i++` didn't give me the answer I expected."  We get these questions daily, and they're always immediately closed and redirected to the [canonical dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433).  But the highest-voted answers at the canonical dup are hard reads, especially for beginners still learning the language, and who are the most likely to be asking the question in the first place.  So I often like to give the OP a quick explanation of their specific issue, while also redirecting.  (The most recent instance was [just last night](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166166).)  But this is also a class of questions where shutting out other answers with a quick close is also important, because we invariably get other helpful newbies popping up with their interpretations of what the problematic expression "should" yield.

(Before someone asks how the canonical dup in this case can be improved, so that people like me aren't forever induced to augment it with a "more-tailored answer": [I've done that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior/51876456#51876456), but it will be a long time before that new answer has any hope of competing on points with the highest-voted answers.)

Comment: That canonical is listed in [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) (tag wiki, under *"Operators, precedence and order of evaluation"*). Perhaps *annotating* the link could solve it? Or isn't there enough space?

Comment: @PeterMortensen As the author of [an FAQ list](http://c-faq.com), I feel comfortable admitting: FAQ lists don't always work.  For this question, especially, the situation is so seemingly bizarre that few people will think of checking the documentation before just heading off to a Q/A site and asking about it.

Comment: It's a little like: you've bought a new car, and you discover that whenever you roll down the right rear window while the radio happens to be playing jazz, the trunk pops open.  You would immediately take the car to the dealer and demand an explanation.  You would not stop and look up "windows" and "radio" in the index of the owner's manual first.  It would never occur to you that this was normal behavior, that everyone else accepts.

Answer (score 2):

If it was a honest mistake, you could explain as much in a comment and then close the post as a dupe even if you have a posted answer. Generally it should be avoided to cast close votes involving posts where you are the author of an answer and therefore partial, but sometimes it is justified.

**However, please consider if the dupe is decent and if the current question has potential to become a better one!** We should not close posts as dupes to an old post just because the old post was there first. That way we can never improve the quality of the site. Instead we should close to post of worst quality as a duplicate to the one with highest quality. Post age is irrelevant, quality is all we care about.

So if you feel confident that you can write a better answer than those in the duplicate, go ahead and write an answer to the new question and maybe propose that the old one gets closed instead.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't both vote to close and answer. By definition, voting to close means that a question can't (or shouldn't) be answered. Answering and then marking as a duplicate makes it look like you should be the only one who's allowed to answer (even if that wasn't your intent).

In some [cases](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415621/dupe-closed-question-is-reopened-then-answered-and-closed-again-as-a-different), this has even been considered outright abuse of the system (although in that case the behavior was very obviously intentional because the gold badge holder in question re-opened, added an answer, and then re-closed it as a dupe).

One option is to simply leave the close voting to someone else. Another option is to delete the answer and re-post it on the dupe target (if it would work there).