# Does this deleted question deserve undeletion?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

Some time ago I've answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67246357/3889449) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1KIS.png) for < 10k users), which was then deleted by the author (whose profile also seems to have been deleted). I've since requested undeletion and bookmarked it. The question is still deleted, has 2 undelete votes pending (one being mine), and there does not seem to be any other way for me to bring attention to it, so I'm asking here on meta.

It seemed like a valid question to me, which is why I answered it in the first place, though I am not entirely sure if it might be that much helpful to anyone else, since it's asking about the meaning of a specific piece of code in the Linux kernel. This might be a valid reason for keeping it deleted, though I'm not sure.

Does the question deserve undeletion, or should it stay deleted?

Comment: status-completed.

Comment: I mean it's a useful question for people doing (linux) kernel development or want to get into it. Just because a topic is niche does not imply it is not useful, niche can still imply hundreds or even thousands of programmers.

Comment: @Gimby yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for making the effort to revive this question & answer.  I agree: It is obscure.  But who cares about obscurity at StackOverflow.  Some of my best Q&As are insane, obscure things.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The question was undeleted thanks to a third voter, so my take from this is that this kind of (very specific) question is ok, as I thought.

Comment: Yeah, a question being about what a very specific piece of code is doing is perfectly fine. It doesn't have to be useful to *every* programmer, so long as it's useful to some of them.

Answer (score -10):

I find your phrasing here rather bizarre. The asker deleted their own question for a reason only known to them, which has nothing to do with whether the question is acceptable by Stack Overflow's rules, yet you appear to be operating on the premise that the question was deleted because it's not acceptable by Stack Overflow's rules... [wat](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/wat)?

A user is allowed to delete their own content at any time, but [because any content posted to Stack Overflow becomes licensed to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing), there's nothing preventing other users of Stack Overflow from un-deleting said content, even against the original author's wishes.

I would argue, therefore, that in this case the original question should have remained deleted. You should have then copied its content into a new question, and then self-answered said question. That way you get rep if the question is upvoted (instead of said rep going to the now-nonexistent original asker), their wish to delete their question remains fulfilled (if only technically), and you wouldn't have had to make a Meta post begging for undelete votes.

Comment: I don't know what phrasing you're referring to, but as far as I can see, no one is questioning why the OP of the linked question self-deleted. This meta is only asking whether the linked question warrants undeletion. I agree that needing to post a meta is not ideal, but that's a limitation of the system not affording something to users that resembles a delete/undelete review queue. I certainly don't see why a *new* question needs to be posted, when there's a perfectly good question already existing. The argument about rep is immaterial IMO.

Comment: *"and you wouldn't have had to make a Meta post begging for undelete votes"* - oh come on now... This was intended to be a very simple and fast meta Q&A about undeleting a post which has been deleted and stale for months, about which I had some doubt. The only reason this meta question got some traction is because I cannot self-accept before 48 hours have passed and therefore it was even "featured on meta". Other than this, I agree with @cigien above. I'm not going to comment any further.

Comment: It's possible this was classwork and the user wanted help, despite warnings not to do this. We see it a lot where a user asks a question, gets an answer, and deletes the question (it becomes more obvious once the answer has upvotes and they can't delete). The user then deleted their account. Since they're gone, we're under no obligation to keep it deleted. In fact we do undelete from mod flags in cases like this where it's not clear why the poster deleted it. Remember, you are licensing your posts to SO under CC-SA

Comment: @Machavity you're saying it would be appropriate to custom flag such a post for undeletion? That seems like a simpler way than asking here on meta. Also, what about if the user was not deleted,  but the Q was deleted without an apparent reason?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli It does. [We have done that before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316118/2370483)

Comment: @Machavity thanks for the link, that's good to know.