# error-- "You can only post once in every 90 minutes" haven't posted for weeks, not from the office too. So why?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

I just tried to post a question today, however i got the message: You can only post once in every 90 minutes. I haven't posted for weeks nor am I in the office. So why is that?

Comment: Do I have anyway of knowing if that's the case with mine? @KevinBrown

Comment: I've read it. But I am not posting from an office.

Comment: From what I see on your account that error doesn't make much sense. Can you add an approximate UTC time that you tried posting to this question rather than just "today" so that if someone else picks it up they can look back to the right place.

Comment: Dangit; @Flexo beat me to the punch!

Comment: Around 10:30p - 11:00p

Comment: also dupe of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259941/103167 (as long as one realizes that offices are not the only cause of IP sharing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your ISP apparently switched up your IP address briefly, handing you one used by another user who had just posted.