# Unable to post a question

Tags: support, questions

I tried to post a question. I formed the question and clicked on the <kbd>Post your question</kbd> button. It kept on loading for next couple of minutes, so I chose to discard and post a fresh one as the question did not get posted successfully. Next time, it is telling me

> You can only post once every 90 minutes.

Why so?

Comment: Why vote down? I am stuck with a problem.

Comment: If you are experiencing network problems, check if another network (say, your mobile network) solves the issue. If you are running into the 90 minutes rate limit, either you *or someone else with the same IP address*, already managed to post in the past 90 minutes. Try again after the time limit has passed. See [Error -- "you can only post once every 90 minutes" but I haven't posted in days](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259941)

Comment: I re-opened because you appear to be experiencing a separate network problem, but that is likely to be local as I see plenty of questions being posted all the time at the moment.

Comment: If there were problems with your question you should have edited it to fix them, not deleted it and posted a new question.