# Circumvented "once per 90-minutes limit" by changing IP address

Tags: bug, asking-questions, rate-limiting, posting

As "[Error -- "you can only post once every 90 minutes" but I haven't posted in days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259941)" says, low-rep users should be blocked from posting more than one question in a 90-minute-period *even if* they use sock-puppets.

Well, the check is broken: 
**I *could* post two questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32991572), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32991282)) with a gap of just *15* minutes.**

It just happens that despite using the same account, I posted from different devices with **different IP addresses**.

Comment: Yup, I misread, sorry about that. The community already stepped in and reopened and edited.

Comment: Its fine. So the community is gonna fix the flaw soon?

Comment: Doesn't seem really easy to abuse though, you use a computer and a phone to ask two questions, what are you going to use to ask a third? Someone else's phone? I guess students might go that far if they are really inclined to spam their homework.

Comment: The community cannot fix bugs. The Stack Overflow developers probably will see what may have happened, and if there is a bug fix it.

Comment: And you used *different IP addresses*. The system prevents posting within 90 minutes from *one* IP address, so this is hardly a bug.

Comment: @Gimby: Well, if you control the internet-access-point and the ISP uses dynamic IPs, you can just force a reconnect. That's somewhat common...

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh, it's a bug, as the rate-limit should apply *even if* one uses multiple IPs, not only if one uses the same IP.

Comment: @Deduplicator: provided the developers see it that way. :-)

Comment: I think its a bug becoz if you have a limit set on the number of questions posted, in a normal way one would think of preventing an user from posting more than one question in 90 mins. And then the IP. Maybe i think it that way because i have less knowledge in this.

Comment: @gimby: i used my phone because i was unable to post a question from my office because of the rate limit on the IP.

Comment: @gimby: i was just trying posting the already typed in question if it works or not. Anyway wierd that nobody else did the same. 

Comment: I don't understand why the account as well as the IP are checked together? surely that's a simple change?!

Comment: @ViniVasundharan for clarity, I'm not accusing you of abusing anything, I'm just musing. Good find!

Comment: @Gimby: no worries. i have taken it in the right spirits.. :)

Comment: I don't really see this as being a big problem. If it's abused by someone to do something malicious, it'l get caught by one of the other many checks in place. If the user is instead posting good quality questions, whats the harm?

Comment: The rate limiting is to slow low rep users down so they have to think about what questions they post and make them count. By using two diff ip addresses, you're still limited to only 2 per 90 minutes, so the rate limiting is still doing it's job.

Comment: @kevin: seems like you have tried posting a third question from a different IP or is it the way it is developed?

Comment: Basing it on IP address covers the most common case of users creating a new account to ask more questions. though, I do agree, if it was based on both IP and User, it would also prevent simply changing your ip address and using the same user, but i suspect that's rare enough that it isn't worth the dev time. And, as i said before, it's still rate limiting them, to one every 90 minutes, per ip address they can acquire.

Comment: I just can't see any reason why the check is "per user, per IP" not just "per user". It seems like that could only happen intentionally but why would you want such a strange feature?

Comment: @Mr.Boy if the check was per user then it woudn't stop someone from creating 100 accounts and posting 100 questions.

Comment: So this does not work well and I am presented with Captchas often that want to verify I'm human. Great.

Comment: LOL WHY DOES THE IP EVEN MATTER? Just embed it on the account level API data and call it a day lol... why would you even make it so an IP is what you check for? That's like... having a front end be the only thing keeping you from 1439293712 character comments and not bothering to check on the API...

Comment: @Lux.Capacitor Did you not read the prior comments?  You seem to mis the fact that if they don't check by IP someone could create 100s of accounts and post all day.

Comment: So... in that case make it "per user" OR "per IP", not a combination. If EITHER your username OR ip address posted within the 90-min window, you get blocked. Seems like an easy enough filter from a programming standpoint,  unless I'm missing something.

Comment: well, this sucks.

Comment: I wrote a good [related answer on IP bans](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96377/why-do-people-use-ip-address-bans-when-ip-addresses-often-change/96499#96499) over on security.SE. Relates to this question pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour should be (but apparently isn't right now) two separately-tracked limits.

- Per-IP: one question per 90 mins (from any and all low-rep accounts on this IP).
- Per-account: one question per 90 mins from a low-rep account.

So working around the rate-limiting would require using a different account on a different IP.

It's still easy to ask two questions per 90 mins if you have a phone and a computer with separate IPs, for example (just keep each of them logged in to a different account).

It's still not very hard to ask lots of questions if you can get a new dynamic IP from your ISP easily, since relogging to different account is also easy, but it's certainly more work and does force you to post the questions from separate accounts, making it harder to keep track of them.

Answer (score -11):

Changing your IP address is assumed to be outside of your control. If you're migrating from a mobile network to a WiFi network, then sure it can happen all the time, but normally, your IP address doesn't change.

However, the logic should instead be using your session cookie and your account as a means of rate-limiting, as this would make more sense. It might actually be a bug in the code which rate limits based on IP address but isn't smart enough to continue and rate limit based on account and session information.

Comment: "normally, your IP address doesn't change" > it changes a lot here. Moving from home to mobile to work to friend house. That are 4 IP addresses already...

Comment: Or just make your router trivially reconnect… (well, assuming your IP isn't static)

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay : My home ɪꜱᴘ provide public ɪᴘ address over ᴅʜᴄᴘ with a very short bail. So by default the public ɪᴘ change very often.

Comment: @bwoebi Doesn't have to be static. Most of the ISPs in the US make your IP "sticky" so even though your DHCP lease might be 7 days, you'll get the same IP on renewal (helps them track bad activity, etc)

Comment: The IP address of your mobile device is likely to change very often, some networks have DHCP lease down to 5 seconds (or even less) to cope with the amount of devices being used by their customers and the limited amount of addresses available.

Comment: @Machavity: Well, here in Germany the ISPs do it simple: You get a new infinite lease every time you connect.

Comment: Anyhow irrelevant because the OP said he used different devices *from the same account*, e.g. laptop and phone not connected to his home network.

Comment: `normally, your IP address doesn't change` I can reboot my router, and BOOM, new IP! This is such a problem for me (IP changes every day & business package for static IP is too expensive), I have a VPS with some code *just* to get around the IP changes. The problem that this question is stating is that the user-account is *ignored* for IP rate limiting, when the user-account itself should be rate-limited as well as the IP.

Comment: How the world has moved on... I remember getting a new IP every time my modem dropped a connection. Actually, it still happens with my fibre connection - just force the modem to reconnect - but at least back then it was common knowledge...