# Does the 90-minute rate limit between successive questions apply to IP addresses only, or to the account as well?

Tags: support, asking-questions, new-users, rate-limiting

This is not addressed by [Circumvented "once per 90-minutes limit" by changing IP address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307577/circumvented-once-per-90-minutes-limit-by-changing-ip-address), as the rate limiting system has been completely rewritten since that question was asked and answered.

Today, I found out that the 40-minute limit for new users asking questions network-wide [only applies to IP addresses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332168/how-was-this-new-user-able-to-post-two-questions-less-than-40-minutes-apart), so it's possible for the same user to bypass this limit simply by changing their IP address:

> > Is it because the rate limit only considers the IP address, and not the account, so if the same account makes the post from a different IP address, it's allowed?
>
> Yup!
>
> Well, for this rate limit at least. There are others, although not all of them are enabled on this site [Meta.SE].

Does this also apply to the 90-minute limit between successive questions for new users here on Stack Overflow, or is this one of the "other" limits that also checks the account?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @CodyGray Because if people can bypass the limit by just changing their IP address, it's a massive loophole in our stringent quality filtering.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is anonymity (= privacy) on the internet, there is no way to reliably identify a certain user. Thus the ban system will *always* have "loopholes".

The only way to make these bans harder to circumvent is to keep the exact rules private. Thus *no answer to your question* is probably the best answer for all of us.

Comment: The fact that a Stack Exchange employee disclosed publicly that the 40-minute limit only applies to IP addresses invalidates this answer.