# Asking more than one question in less than 90 minutes

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, rate-limiting

Some time ago I could post more than one question in less than 90 minutes. I thought the bug would have been fixed until I saw this user also posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195479/the-name-file-does-not-exist-in-current-context-in-signal-r-hub-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195888/the-name-url-does-not-exist-in-current-conext-in-signal-r-hub-class) in a gap of 10 minutes or may be less.

This post is to notify that still an user is able to post more than one question in less than 90 minutes.. Or did I miss something?  Has the constraint been removed?

Comment: The limit only applies to low reputation users (< 125 points).

Comment: Related: [Error -- "you can only post once every 90 minutes" but I haven't posted in days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259941)

Answer (score 7):

This holds for users with < 125 reputation points, as described in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).