# Error - "You can only post once every 90 minutes." . I am behind a proxy server used by hundreds of people

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I recently found an error saying "You can only post once every 90 minutes.". To searched on meta for the reason it may be happening, I came across this question -

[Error -- "you can only post once every 90 minutes" but I haven't posted in days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259941/error-you-can-only-post-once-every-90-minutes-but-i-havent-posted-in-days)

I use Internet services provided by my college.

The college uses Proxy server and only 2 or 3 IPs are exposed to the internet. And I feel the restriction must be made based on user and not IP Address.

Comment: Hare you read the answer?  **The rate limit applies to IP addresses (until you reach 125 points, see The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide).**

Answer (score 17):

The restriction is made per IP address for a good reason. People commonly create account after account from the same IP address to circumvent per-account limits. This prevents those people from inundating the site with questions.

This limit goes away once you pass the 125 reputation threshold, which is a reasonably low bar for legitimate accounts. Anyone above that limit isn't impacted by the presence of others at their same location.

It's a tradeoff between artificially rate-limiting some new users and preventing the site from being overrun by people circumventing per-account limits. From what I've seen, this tends to not harm that many legitimate users, but it cuts down on a lot of abuse.

Comment: Just to add to this, if a lot of new users are asking questions from a university, they probably could just search instead of asking anyway.

Comment: cont of Bill's comment: since the questions they have are the mostly the same as previous ones.