# Don't count failed post submissions towards post limit

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I've just experienced this issue right now and it is incredibly annoying.

I tried to post a question regarding a problem I'm currently having, but the title was the same as another post. I changed the title and then tried to re-submit, but was met with the "You can only post once every 90 minutes." error. Now I am stuck waiting 90 minutes before I can post the issue I need help with.

A failed submission of a post should not count towards a user's post limit, it should allow the user to make the corrections required and then submit. It is possible this is a bug that needs fixed, or it may be the intended design of the system, but either way I personally think this is a big flaw.

Comment: Maybe check that other post with the same title and see if it already has the answer to what you want to ask.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've tried all of the solutions in all of the related posts I could find to no avail.

Comment: So you typed in the title, and the other post appeared in the ["questions that may already have your answer" dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zDBH.png)...and you ignored it. I don't see a reason for this to change. You had a likely highly-relevant piece of information handed to you on a silver platter but insisted on posting your question anyways. This is exactly what the time limit is for.

Comment: I didn't ignore it. I had already visited that post, as well as every other one in the list and others. None of the solutions in those posts got the functionality I'm trying to implement working, hence me creating my own post. This has nothing to do with "ignoring" anything or "insisting" on posting what you seem to assume was a pointless post.

Comment: The question title cannot be same if you have checked other questions and determined that the answers aren't sufficient. It's high likely that your question is then either a broad question, would lack details that would distinguish your question towards the question with the same title or that the title doesn't reflect the content.

Comment: Is it possible that this is actually an IP issue and the timing with the title issue is a co-incidence? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259941/error-you-can-only-post-once-every-90-minutes-but-i-havent-posted-in-days Meaning that had the title not been a duplicate it would have shown the 90 minutes warning right away.

Comment: Regardless of whether the question itself or op possibly missing any heads up's the system have given him, a question that failed to submit shouldn't trigger the post limit. Seeing that no actual question was posted.

Comment: Regardless of whether there is a problem with the post limit or not, 90 minutes should not be a problem. This site is not intended to be a place where people get their urgent questions answered quickly. (Sometimes that does happen, but it's not the main point.)

Comment: But let's not make assumptions about the quality of the post that we haven't actually seen based on the fact that it had the same title as a previous post. People post garbage with unique titles all the time, so there's no reason the opposite couldn't happen as well.

Comment: @KarelG I don't understand your point "the question title cannot be same if you have checked other questions". Posts I have read, from that list or otherwise, don't have any affect on what I title my post. I wasn't aware posts required a unique title, so I titled it exactly what was happening, it turns out someone else had done the same.

Edit: I can also assure you that the question is very specific and contains all of the details relating to what I have done/tried from all of the other posts I have read on the matter.

Comment: @BSMP this may be a possibility. I am posting from within an office, so there could be an issue with multiple posts from the same IP address.

Comment: _"I wasn't aware posts required a unique title"_ Fair enough; that's a non-obvious rule. Showing duplicate title guidance as a JIT popup, instead of waiting until you hit the "post" button, seems like a good idea.

Comment: OK, well, where is this question that is not a duplicate?  Link?

Comment: @MartinJames my question related to PHP file uploading always being empty. Having read dozens of posts on the matter and trying all of the solutions within, I was unable to get the functionality working, so I wanted to pose my own question with how I'm implementing it, and all of the relevant info regarding what I had already changed, settings that were applied, environment, etc. That way I could hopefully get help to understand why, in my specific case, this still wasn't working.

Comment: It is probably not a dupe - it is a bug report.

Answer (score 7):

I think you got it backwards. These 90 minutes are there not to penalise you but to help.

You are granted that time to learn and memorise few useful things:

- Question titles are considered very important matter at Stack Overflow
- If there is a post with same title as your it is shown to you in the "questions that may already have your answer" list and you are expected to study it and, if your question differs, also make a different title
- If you fail to make a proper title system will grant you 90 more minutes to work on improving it

These things may be difficult to remember for a new user but don't you worry: if you happen to forget something system will help you again with the same 90-minutes timeout.

---

PS. Just in unlikely case if you expected to get help urgently, give a read to [guidance here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/839601).

> <sup>Nobody is going to see that you need an answer ASAP and then drop everything they're doing in order to help you. Your emergencies are your own... It might seem paradoxical, but if you're in a hurry, the best thing you can do is slow down...</sup>

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I think 90 minutes is a very excessive amount of time to absorb a very small amount of information and make a very small edit. As I have mentioned above, the posts listed under my title were all ones I had already seen, I was posting my question having tried everything I could and therefore really requiring help specific to me/my issue. Having a post limit makes perfect sense, but a 90 minute timeout for a wrong title (and not just trying to post a lot) seems too much to me.

Comment: not really excessive, unless you're in a hurry @Abysinian (in the latter case refer guidance I pointed in PS). To me for example just preparing most of my questions takes 3-5 times more than these tiny 90 minutes. Heck I recall spending weeks on some of my questions

Comment: I'm not in a hurry to get the answer, but losing 90 minutes of visibility on the post means it could be tomorrow before I can actually look at what answers have come in, test them and provide feedback on the results. Had the timeout only been 5-10 minutes for the title not being unique it's entirely possible I could be looking into possible answers right now - people can be very quick at responding. I agree people should be sure they have reviewed relevant posts and have a well written and thought out post, but I don't agree with a 90 minute wait for a non-unique title.

Comment: hmmm I wonder how comes that "losing visibility" like that on my own questions (which as I mentioned take hours or days or even weeks to prepare) doesn't hurt me. I get desired answers, upvotes and badges, no matter if it took me 90/900 minutes more or less to prepare

Comment: @Abysinian on a website where questions and answers are supposed to be for the long (eternal?) term, how is 90 minutes REALLY an issue?

Comment: It's pretty commonly an issue for anyone who only has a small amount of time to work on a project on their off-time. If you've only got an hour or so a few days a week & run into an issue, then you want to post the question when you have that availability; hopefully you'll have an answer by your next window. If you're forced to wait 90 mins then days might go by before you can post it again, which then means you have to try & remember everything about the question which wastes yet more time.  90 minutes could lead to days or weeks. That's a needless waste of time & nothing to do with urgency.

Comment: @JBC issue being common hardly justifies bending site rules. For comparison, it is pretty common to have a homework on a tight deadline (I have a relative studying CS and someimes deadlines are just crazy) but this doesn't help when students dump no-effort assignments here

Comment: @gnat That's operating under the assumption that a duplicate title is actually a common or duplicate problem, which isn't necessarily true.

Comment: @Patrice because it is terrible design and makes for an awful user experience. Why even let me try to submit the post at all with a non-unique title if you're just going to penalise me for doing so? Display a warning by the title and disable the submission button, problem solved.

Comment: @JBC no, not at all I wonder what part of my post you misread to get to a conclusion like that. "you are expected to study it and, if your question differs, also make a different title"

Comment: @JBC gets it exactly. Me having to wait 90 minutes to post again may mean I can't get round to posting it until tomorrow, which means it's not _just_ 90 minutes that I've lost, it's potentially a whole day, maybe more. Whether I need the answer today or in a month, there's just no need whatsoever to make me wait 90 minutes before I can post something because my title wasn't unique.

Comment: @gnat I was responding to the above comments, not your post directly.  Lack of characters to @ them, though.

Comment: @Abysinian ok then, let me ask again "in the grand scheme of things, where your question is meant to be ETERNAL, how is 1 day REALLY an issue?" Seriously. I get that it's unfortunate to be hit by this. Seriously I do. I just fail to see why it needs a changing. It's inconvenient more than a real issue in my opinion

Comment: @Patrice if a piece of functionality is an inconvenience to users, is bad design/UX and unnecessary it warrants changing in my opinion. JBC hit the nail on the head pretty well with their reply to you. A day can be a long (and very unnecessary) amount of time to lose when you're looking for an answer to a problem. Once the answer is provided and that becomes eternal someone else can find it and try it in 5 minutes and in 5 minutes their problem is solved - excellent. Me getting that solution took a day or more longer than it should have just because of a piece of pointless functionality.

Comment: @Patrice I'm not saying this is a huge problem and needs immediate attention, but it's just _bad_ and has no reason to be there. **Prevent** your users from making errors **before** they make them. Don't let them make one and then punish them for it.

Comment: @Abysinian So, what I read here is "but I need my answer ASAP", which, AGAIN, isn't important for us. I am not trying to debate the fact that its inconvenient, or that I would grumble A LOT if it happened to me. But at the end of the day, it's a very edge case situation, that doesn't impact you much. If you come here to post because you need an answer NAO.... well then you may need to revisit how you use Stack.

Comment: @Patrice there's a difference between needing an answer _now_ (not me) and needing one in a timely manner (me). Adding significant delays to someone acquiring their answer (potentially hours, days, or more depending on the situation) starts to eat into that "timely manner" part. I'm not, nor have I ever, used this site to try and get answers to things I need _now_, but it wouldn't matter if I _always_ used it for things I wanted _right now_. The point about the functionality itself being inconvenient and unnecessary is what matters here, and why, in my opinion, it should be changed.

Comment: Many things are inconvenient and unnecessary.  To judge whether effort should be applied to fix them means asking 'how inconvenient and unnecessary'.  If the answer to that is 'it hardly ever happens that an OP with a 90 minute restriction AND a duplicate title AND wants to post in a shorter interval is so bothered as to raise a change request' then SO developer effort will probably not be spent on it.

Comment: @MartinJames ...especially if it additionally carries a really serious drawback, like in this case: "allowing to repost immediately will deprive inexperienced asker opportunity to learn fundamental things about how to ask (importance of title and of checking questions that may already have their answer)"

Comment: @gnat I'd say you're overstating the benefit here.  You can accomplish similar edification without such a long delay.  Even 30 minutes would be a long time to wait, yet simultaneously be much more agreeable.  The real issue here is not so much that a delay exists, but the magnitude of it.  I doubt you'd find a meaningful reduction in quality by lowering the delay.

Comment: your math doesn't look compelling @JBC - let's see what is expected of asker. 1) Study the error message and realise what exactly they did wrong 2) discover and study "questions that may have your answer" 3) find and study that other question with identical title and its answers and find out if it's different or not. Keep in mind that we're talking about new inexperienced user who may do many things slowly. The last but not the least - they need to figure new corrected title - heck, this thing alone often takes more than 30 minutes when I write my questions even though I'm quite experienced

Comment: @gnat you didn't wait 90 minutes between the comments either, despite saying the same thing multiple times.

Comment: @ingotangjingle I wrote about question titles, not about comments