# Question wasn't even published, but there is a 90 minute cooldown

Tags: bug

I didn't ask a question on any of the sibling sites, however I have a 90 minute cool down to ask a question. Any suggestion as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: see also [Don't count failed post submissions towards post limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355585/dont-count-failed-post-submissions-towards-post-limit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Related Help Center page:

[Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) > [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

---

[Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

> ***This block is only temporary, but much longer blocks exist in the system.*** We're trying to slow you down and provide you with more guidance now, in hopes that you avoid a much longer period where the system won't accept questions from your account. Please take some time to revisit and improve your previous questions wherever possible.

---

This is not a bug, it is by design. Out of your 5 visible (non-deleted) questions, the vote count is +1,-4 netting a -3.

This gives your questions an average vote rating of -0.6. As a result, the system has taken to beginning the process of rate limiting. While you encountered a 90 minute limit this first time, it will only get stricter over time if the overall rating of your questions does not improve to positive territory. It will get especially worse if your questions begin to get closed or deleted.

90 minutes is a very small deterrent, I would suggest you go through some of the suggested reading related to this issue so that you don't wind up with a stricter limit.