# Timer for posting too many questions within 90 minutes conflicts with autosave

Tags: bug

I wrote this question which seems to have autosaved while I was posting

[How do I perform a logical If..then in powershell against JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53212232/10089398)

The issue is that while posting I received a message that I had already posted within the 90 minute interval, and I had not.

I assume that what actually happened is a JSON autosave in the background which triggered the warning.

Just a heads up that this condition exists, namely a new user who posts a long question will have issues submitting that question until the timer resets.

(PS: I got a similar timeout here, which says I can only post once every 20 minutes. Oy veh.)

EDIT:

I am on a shared proxy server in a large company, so that shared IP address may be the culprit.

Comment: Your explanation seems possible, though I'm wondering about another case; is your wifi shared? Such as in a workplace? Because [the rate limit applies to IP addresses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259942/7795130), so if someone on your network posted a question in the last hour, that could trigger it too.

Comment: Related: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/363946)

Comment: I do not think there is an autosave function that could trigger rate limiting. Drafts are saved in your browsers local storage.

Comment: This is why we generally recommend drafting your question offline (there are a number of Markdown editors available to help) and then copy-pasting into the question box.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Who is "we"? I've never heard that recommendation before and doesnt sound like it should be needed as shared IP seems to be the explanation anyway.

Comment: It is the "royal we" :-)