# Unable to post my question

Tags: support, bug, asking-questions

I tried posting my question on Stack Overflow but am unable to do so.

I have written my question completely and then reviewed it and I got the following notification on the right top of the page:

> Your question is ready to publish!
>  Our automated system checked
>   for ways to improve your question and found none.

I then pressed 'Post your question' but I am getting

> You can only post once every 90 minutes.

I got this notification after my first attempt.

I'm not able to find where my question is, there is no notification for successful posting question either.

Comment: Have you posted and deleted a question some minutes ago? (no longer than 90 minutes ago)

Comment: When I posted at first time, I got "You can only post once every 90 minutes." but, I am unable to find the question not even in my profile.

Comment: Are you using some sort of shared connection? University, company, something like that?

Comment: No @yivi , nothing such

Comment: I was trying since 4-5 hours, this is now fixed somehow. I am able to post the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error -- "you can only post once every 90 minutes" but I haven't posted in days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259941/error-you-can-only-post-once-every-90-minutes-but-i-havent-posted-in-days)