# What do you think about a "do some research" delay before posting a question for very low rep users?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

I want to start a little discussion on how to avoid all the badly formatted questions where some research on the internet would have brought up thousands of results.

I searched Meta.SO (and meta.stackexchange.com) and only stumbled accross [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294).

My suggestion is simple but perhaps may be effectual:

**Let very low rep users post a question only after a short delay of time.**

This might not be politically incorrect as it won't disallow them to ask a question, but they will be forced to take a small amount of time to think about their problem and to do research.

In concrete: They can click the *Ask Question* button, and they can begin entering their question. But the *Post Your Question* button is greyed out like it is in the review for 5 minutes (or another amount of time), and counts down the time with some JavaScript.

It could look like this:

[image: This is how the suggestion could look like]

So in the meantime, the user can do some research or improve their question.

I thought about a limit of 10-15 reputation for having this displayed. Most times, I see bad questions posted by 1-10 rep users, but I think we don't have to worry much about people above this limit.

For all those who get scared by the idea of a JavaScript countdown: Yeah, this doesn't stop them from posting the questions, but, if they know a way around it by editing the DOM with the developer tools and posting their question, it will be okay - we can assume they have enough knowledge to know what they are doing and so the question should also be a good one.

Comment: The intention is noble, but something like this won't help, I'm afraid.  It will just make people wait to post the question.  At which point, it will be downvoted *then*, rather than right away.  Either way, it won't force people to research.  Nothing can do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

Research has never been a reason not to let someone ask a question.

That's what downvotes are for:

[image]

Not only does it take away from our utility (fast answers to questions), it imposes a silly requirement that may not even be applicable in most circumstances.

Comment: This, a thousand times this.  Prior research has *never* been a requirement for asking questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: To my mind it's a requirement for asking a *good* question. Indeed, that's in the help center article about how to ask a good question, almost at the very top: "Search, and research"

Comment: @JonSkeet If we were to limit askable questions to only 'good questions', that'd be some wicked machine learning. Of course, the Donald Rumsfeld quote is applicable here, "There are known knowns, known unknowns, and unknown unknowns." We exist to answer all three; and the last is most difficult to research.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I prefer to call it "adequate prior knowledge of the subject matter."  If a person writes a non-trivial `icanhazcodez` question without showing their prior effort, but it's sufficiently constrained in scope, it's still a perfectly good question, *assuming the OP has sufficient background knowledge to understand the answer.*  Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660127/faster-way-to-swap-endianness-in-c-sharp-with-32-bit-words

Comment: Of course, that doesn't necessarily make it a high quality question, it just means that it's not closeable under the current crop of close reasons.  It's still downvoteable, however.  Note that the downvote button says "it is unclear or not useful."  Good, broadly applicable code samples are useful to everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your answers at first. I knew this might get downvoted, but thats what opinion based meta is for. I haven't thought from the perspective of "fast answers" yet, but focused on the SO [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) where it says "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)". For me this seemed to tell me "do some research first to find an answer".

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap: We still expect people to be specific about their problem.  Showing your work is a great way to do that.  Many `sendmetehcodez` questions are either too broad or unclear.  Unanswerable questions don't help anyone.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'd argue that questions that are trivially answerable with research don't help anyone. If a search for the words in the title get a hit (say in the top 3) from primary documentation (e.g. MSDN, Javadoc) which answers the question clearly, then I don't see that having it on SO is a good thing - and if it gets an answer, that merely encourages the questioner not to bother doing research next time, either. This isn't against "simple" questions, mind you - there are plenty of questions which are easy once you know the answer, but hard to research.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Too bad we don't have a General Reference close reason.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Absolutely. I'd be very much in favour of that.

Comment: I wouldn't, for the following reasons:

1. I 'trust' Stack Overflow answers because they have an element of voting to them that other sites do not have (nor do they have the eyeballs to make voting relevant).

2. If there's an answer without an expansive example, we have the opportunity to add one in; we can't simply edit MSDN because their page on how to deal with Filtered Indexes sucks.

3. Finally, there's a profit motive to keep it up to date -- once an answer goes out of date, a new answer can always be added and voted up. This is not true for pure documentation.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: The pure documentation is more likely to be up-to-date than an answer which refers to it though. If I want to know "How many overloads are there for string.Join?" I'm going to trust MSDN more than a Stack Overflow answer from 2010... and someone else adding a new answer is fairly pointless when *that* will become out of date in another year...

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I accepted this now and will close this discussion, as your arguments inside the answer and the comments are absolutely clear and reasonable to me. Thanks for the additional input. I liked to see your opinion and really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, my personal experience with *free to ask immediately* approach has been [rather negative](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/test-failed-a-question-from-unregistered-0-score-account) but I can't tell, maybe it's just me and maybe things typically tend to go better than that.

From what I learned so far, my understanding is that ability to quickly post a question has been considered one of key features when Stack Overflow was created. [Podcast #23](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W25450) is fairly straightforward about this (bold font in below quote is mine):

> **the way we built the site, the really low friction nature of it**...
>
> I think every programmer should want this system to exist, again, for their own reasons, right?  Like, they just want answers to their freakin' programming questions.  They don't want to deal with a lot of stupid overhead, a lot of form logins, or searching a bunch of stuff.  **They just want a quick and dirty way to put in a question** and get a reasonable answer...

On the other hand, I learned that above is not an absolute requirement.

For example, it has been compromised about two years after podcast when [registration was introduced at SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107163/165773), forcing users to pass through "form logins" prior to asking their first question:

> > I know SO's policy is "you don't have to register to ask questions,"
>
> I have decided this policy no longer makes sense...

One can also argue that it was further compromised recently, when asking questions became [rate-limited to 1 per 90 minutes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256324/839601) for users having less than 125 rep. Granted, it's not exactly the same as delaying the first question, but pretty close. And the reasoning to justify the increased delay reads pretty generic:

> If you need to ask questions more than every 1.5 hours, you *probably* aren't putting enough thought, time or both into your questions, which isn't fair to us, as it diminishes the perceived quality of the resource we're working very hard to build and maintain.
>
> Note, this setting is only different on Stack Overflow, the limit is a bit higher on the rest of the sites in our network. We had to increase the amount of time folks need to wait until they become established users because *people would request that we help them through every task they undertook during their work day*. This is supposed to be Q&A, not pair programming.