# Possible solution to “You can only post once every 90 minutes” at Work

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The way I see it, several changes need to be made for users at work sharing the same IP address. This is just what I think.

1. Change the message to 'your IP address' instead of 'you cannot'. This would really help new users who would otherwise just get angry and think the site is malfunctioning.
2. The message should show how many minutes are left of the 90 before you can post again. This would let those of us who are desperate for a quick answer look elsewhere instead of wasting time refreshing the page.

**Possible Solution to the entire problem:**

Do not limit question asking by IP address and instead limit account creation by IP address. So this means, if you ask a question from account A, you cannot create a new account B from the same IP until 90 minutes are up. You should however be allowed to use another account (which was already created) to ask a question from the same IP without any time penalties.

I feel these changes would greatly improve the way new users interact with the site. Any feedback is welcome!

**Edit:**
This will solve the following:

1. Spammers cannot create second accounts immediately.
2. Users at work can use the site properly (using their separate
   accounts).
3. 90 minute penalty can be enforced on the account - so the same user
   cannot ask more than 1 question every 90 minutes. (This will not
   affect office workers as they don't share accounts.)

I don't see the point in letting users create accounts on SO if they aren't allowed to post questions with that account for 90 minutes. (Shared IP at work.) So what's the point?

*It should be noted that this suggestion is based with the user under 125 rep in mind.*

**Edit 2:**

I think everyone is misinterpreting my post. I'm not talking about removing this feature but rather changing it so that it doesn't affect those of us using the site from work.

Comment: Maybe you should add some context or link to the question where this 'feature' is discussed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman What do you mean? This is a proposed solution to a problem that all of us under 125 rep experience. It's a major flaw in the site (proven by the multiple duplicate questions about it in the metas).

Comment: [This explains why it is in use](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256323/questions-are-now-rate-limited-to-1-per-90-minutes/256324#256324). 125 rep is not that hard to get if you are serious about it. I don't think this feature should be changed, as there is no way you can say if 2 accounts from the same ip are from the same person or from 2 co-workers. That said, the first part of this feature-request (changing the message) looks okay to me.

Comment: @Sumurai8 True, but what if you use SO only at work? And never from home (due to time constraints and what not). You can't but my solution cuts down the effect on the proper user (I've been trying to post a question for the past 30 minutes), especially in really big firms (over 5000 employees at my branch right now. - Most of them sharing the same IP..)

Comment: @Sumurai8 The post you linked me to is not what I'm trying to address here. I'm talking about office workers sharing the same IP.

Comment: It explains why this feature is put into place and put at 90 minutes. It is important to understand that before judging this feature request and deciding if this feature request would also do a good job at tackling that problem. Malicious users can simply create a second account, then ask twice as much questions, or three account and ask thee times the questions. As soon as they create an extra account, the system can not do anything to rate limit them anymore. I find that a big difference.

Comment: I think everyone is misinterpreting my post. I'm not talking about removing this feature but rather changing it so that it doesn't affect those of us using the site from work.

Comment: Limiting account creation will *not help*. You could still create a new account every 90 minutes and then still use those accounts to ask multiple questions within minutes. The solution is for you to get 125 points of reputation. *This is not that hard*.

Comment: `those of us who are desperate for a quick answer` should just GTFO and do some more research. We are overrun with people who "just want a quick answer" and do not know or care about the goal of SO, which is to create a high quality repository of useful content. It is **not** about solving your individual problem as fast as possible. If you get that message, take it as an indication to either earn more rep so that the rate limiting does not affect you anymore, or use the time until you can ask again to do more research (you can _never_ do enough) and polish your question.

Comment: Sample scenario: Individual A has done a lot of research on a problem he's been having and rather than get help from his superior he decides to submit a clear and detailed question to SO. After typing out said question, he presses the submit button, only to be denied saying he has to wait 90 minutes to submit a question. Individual A is confused. This is his first time posting on SO so how could he get a warning like this? He does not realize that the site is warning him because his work mate, in the next cubicle, is also asking on SO **using the same IP**. So your solution is to GTFO? @l4mpi

Comment: Addendum to your scenario: Individual A is confused, searches for reasons why this message would appear, and immediately finds many related questions on meta.SO/SE via google. A realizes this is a simple and effective measure against abuse which is trivially overcome by getting 125 rep. Confusion averted. I agree that the message can be confusing, but then only the message should be changed, not the behaviour. My point is, SO does not care if somebody _needs a quick answer_, SO only cares about quality content. If your answer can't wait 90 minutes, pay a consultant instead of asking on SO.

Comment: Quite an assumption, thinking a new user would stumble across the metas like that but lets ignore that. The solution I proposed above solves this problem and the only flaw I see in it is that users who own multiple accounts can cheat the system. But **only users who already own multiple accounts**, meaning new accounts cannot be created solely for this purpose. I also think that any user who already owns multiple accounts on a site like SO is capable of using a proxy and a different account to post multiple times in 90 minutes. The only people really affected by this *fence* are ppl like us.

Comment: And to repeat myself for the nth time, I'm not trying to remove this feature, but rather to change the way it's being implemented to increase its efficiency.

Comment: Yes, sadly it's quite an assumption that new users are able to use google. And as for "making the feature more effective", you would achieve exactly the opposite. The SE team has had good reasons to put this filter in place, and _there is already another rate limiting based on accounts_, namely that each account can only ask 6 questions per day (which is about 4 too many IMO). And again, if you're so reliant on SO that you're heavily affected by waiting 90 minutes, **you're doing it wrong**. Asking questions on SO is a privilege, a precious, depletable resource, treat it like this.

Comment: Please stop. Scroll up and read my post all over again. And read it again. The problem is not when I want to post more than once every 90 minutes. The problem is when everyone at work is posting questions and some of us never get to post a single one. Get it? Our IP's are shared.

Comment: Please read _my_ posts. Do you need capslock? Here: **IF YOU ARE SO HEAVILY DEPENDEND ON GETTING AN ANSWER FROM STACK OVERFLOW THAT YOU CANNOT WAIT 90 MINUTES TO DO SO, DESPITE NOT EVEN CONTRIBUTING ENOUGH TO THE SITE TO EARN 125 REPUTATION, YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG**. SO does not even care if it's you or your co-worker who tries to ask the question, all the SO software sees is that there are too many questions from low-rep users originating from your companys IP. Want to avoid that? GO EARN 125 REPUTATION. The behaviour you have observed is _not a bug, it's a feature_.

Comment: Also, if your proposed solution would be implemented, people would be blocked from creating accounts if they are using a shared IP at a company or university, which is arguably worse than a short question block as it would block them from all participation, including the posting of answers.

Comment: Your augment is ridiculous. If it was an intended feature, why not just stop all users below 125 rep from asking questions? Because that's the kind of impact it has on new users with shared IPs. About my solution: the account block would also be short (90 mins) and yes, guests won't be able to make new accounts to answer questions (a very low % of office users) but that's a worthy sacrifice for the number of office users who get to ask questions. The metas exist for this precise reason (no, not all intended features stay the same forever) and I've made my point.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you think people not being able to create accounts and _answer_ questions is "a worthy sacrifice" just so that a few low-rep users can _ask_ more questions? You're right, this is completely ridiculous. Pro tip: that your only use case on SO is asking doesn't mean this is true for all new users. Also, there are many other kinds of shared IPs than offices, e.g. universities. But of course, I guess it could be totally worth it for all of your important questions about missing quotes in SQL statements that cannot wait 90 minutes...

Comment: Let's not go for cheap shots at the sacrifice of a meaningful discussion. At any rate, this one's over. I've made my point.

Comment: Not being able to create an account (and do anything) is a bigger problem then having to wait 90 minutes to post a question. And spammers can just create accounts once every 90 minutes and then use them all to spam when they are ready. This would just hurt the honest user and help the spammer.

Comment: @l4mpi - I agree that 'desperate for a quick answer' isn't what SO is for. However, the GTFO/caps/bold is probably not helpful to the debate you're having. I've reported the 'GTFO' to a moderator - respectful discourse please.

Comment: @l4mpi How do you earn 125 reputation without asking or answering?

Comment: @DamianYerrick by spamming edit suggestions; you get 2 rep for each approved edit. Given the state of the review queues you can basically edit whatever you want and as long as you don't deface a post so obviously that even a robo reviewer notices, it will be approved. There's more than enough people who got to >1k rep with basically nothing but crap edits. But of course, the better way would simply be answering questions - afaik the rate limit for answers from low-rep users should be separate from the one for questions.

Answer (score 22):

From the comments, there is a real problem here, but it's not the one you're focused on.

The real problem is that a user spends time and effort typing up a question and then is unable to save it.  That is a data loss bug.

I think we need to ability to save a question to the user profile unconditionally.  The usual checks can be used to prevent that question from becoming public.

These saved but not public questions would be advantageous for a number of cases:

- Tripped the rate limit, for accounts with low reputation.
- Automatic detection of related questions (probable duplicates) is much, much better after the question body has been entered.
- Linked to external content on a forbidden site.

In all these cases, discarding the user's effort is not a necessary step in keeping the site clean.  In the case of reviewing duplicates, losing your progress in the question asking process is a clear barrier to the OP checking the autogenerated related list before making the question public.  Even for accounts or IPs which have an outright question ban, wouldn't it be kinder to give the user a chance to copy their work?

These private drafts of questions could have a limited lifetime before they get auto-deleted, if space on the server is a concern.

Comment: As long as it's limited to one or even a handful drafts per account, I doubt space will ever become the limiting factor.

Answer (score -10):

> If you can think of a better way to handle this, go for it. One has yet to be presented.

1. Track usage statistics for IP addresses. If these are high-usage IP addresses, it is likely a commercial enterprise, and the users will be professionals seeking information or wishing to offer information. If the site has over certain volume, lower the wait time proportionally to less than 90 minutes.
2. If sites have a high volume and low incidence of spam or down-voted responses, add them to a white-list and do not enforce the 90 minute wait time.
3. If 1. and 2. do not apply, if you suspect that one person is opening multiple accounts in order to post poorly (i.e. spam) check the creation date of the account. If there are multiple new accounts for the same IP address, then invoke the 90 minute rule.

As always, the solution comes from understanding what you want to accomplish. If you want to block professionals working on a corporate campus, the current rule is good. If you want to block someone who is not serious and degrades the experience for others, try to differentiate them from those who have done nothing wrong.

Comment: how do you determine what makes a *"high-usage IP address"*?

Answer (score -12):

John is right, and the responses he received are rude, hostile, and not helpful.
I am at a site with 3000 technical people and I have a serious question that I have been polishing all morning. Every time I try to post it, I get the message

> You can only post once every 90 minutes.

I only have 11 reputation points because I became disconnected from my original account when I changed jobs 6 years back.

I *cannot* earn points, because I cannot post, because I do not have enough points. I probably don't even have enough to post this, and I cannot post a comment because I don't have enough points.

So, go ahead and be glib and arrogant, but I have been on Stack Overflow for many years now, and I still cannot even ask a question yet.

If it sounds like the unhelpful responses have upset me, you are right.

Comment: While it really sucks that you are caught in this predicament due to this IP based restriction, it really is an important restriction. Without it, it would be easier for people to abuse the restriction by simply creating more accounts. While this does occasionally catch legitimate users in traps like this, it has been found to be necessary to help keep the site from being overrun in very low quality or spam posts.

Comment: Ever think of asking a question from your phone on mobile data or at home? You know, places with different IP addresses? You get glib answers because you want SO to work around something that is a lot easier for YOU to work around.

Comment: "I became disconnnected from my original account" Then [ask the administrators to merge this account with your original account](http://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: Sorry, my flip phone does not access Stack Overflow. 
How about, instead, finding a way to address the problem user, without punishing a person who seriously needs to talk to other knowledgeable users, and would love to contribute? It is never morally acceptable to take your problem and make it my problem. While I like to be cooperative, that is just shabby behavior.

Comment: I did ask the administrators to merge my accounts. However, I only got one of the two emails I was supposed to get, and, I am actually at work with deadlines and complex research, so time is an issue, and I could not follow up on that yet again. I am only responding now because I have been fighting to post on Stack Overflow for years, and just cannot do it. I can't be the only person this affects.

Comment: If _you_ can think of a better way to handle this, go for it. One has yet to be presented. Look at it this way: Should speed limits be removed because I have a long commute and a short time to travel, but I am a good driver? (Hypothetical. I also realize these are different degrees of restrictions. Best I have.) I only need to drive a _little_ faster to make it, but it would still be speeding. Speed limits are there so people don't drive recklessly fast and put other people in danger. This restriction is similar: The rate limit is there so people don't post too fast and overwhelm the site.

Comment: I will think about it and respond.

In the meantime, the people who downvoted the original question should reconsider, because it is a question with merit. It does not deserve to be treated contemptuously.

(First idea: prorate the number of posts based on the number of accesses from the same IP address. Since we have a campus with 6000 employees, many of whom have technical roles, the time limit should be correspondingly shorter than at a single spammer's home computer with one user.)

Comment: Feature requests are typically voted on differently on meta- It's not that the post is a bad one, but rather that people disagree with the feature request. As for your idea, that is a decent one, but you'd then also have to address school campuses. If someone wants to spam or post low quality questions (the restriction is not _just_ for spam) they could very easily be at a college campus, where hundreds or thousands (depending on the college size) of people could be hitting the network. (This restriction does work network wide. This needs considered as well.) Public wifi needs considered too.

Comment: one can earn up to 2K reputation by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), without any IP address limits - is there anything stopping you from hopping over that 125 rep IP-barrier this way?

Comment: @gnat I believe you can only earn a maximum 1K rep by editing. Your point still stands though, of course.

Comment: Thanks, @gnat, that is a good suggestion. I do appreciate its thoughtfulness. I personally do not feel I have the right to edit or change anything that anyone else says, because that may alter the meaning of what they originally meant. I realize this is not the philosophy of the site, but I would prefer to comment or answer, especially if code snippets are involved. And I am not going to insult anyone by correcting spelling, since many people are not native English speakers. So I won't ever warm up to editing, I'm afraid.

Comment: hmm your hesitation makes good sense because edits that alter the meaning are considered risky. [Safe philosophy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194863/165773) of editing here differs from that of say, Wikipedia: "to readers (including original author of the edited content)... it shouldn't look like you introduced something that wasn't there in the mind of original author". Still, this leaves quite a lot of opportunities - for example fixing spelling and formatting in text ([not code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/839601)) are well known as welcome and safe

Comment: @Kendra, you make good points about public institutions. However, there could still be a white list of private institutions, or any other IP addresses associated with a preponderance of high-quality activity and small amounts of inappropriate activity. It won't, I'm afraid, help the serious user who is unfortunately sharing IP's with undesirable posters. But it is better than punishing everyone indiscriminately.

Comment: @patricksweeney - Sorry I was unclear on my first post. The "glib answers" comment was in response to the very poor responses made to the original poster up above. It seemed that people were more interested in attacking each possible shortcoming of his ideas than in working with him to open a dialog to identify an issue and collaborate on a response. So, yes, they were glib and rude, but I was not saying that I have been subject to glib or rude responses. I am sorry if I gave that impression.