# Is this a new form of homework abuse / help-vampirism?

Tags: discussion, homework, abuse

A user posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61533632/6879826) seeking help with debugging. I answered, and shortly after when I looked at the page I saw that the user had deleted their account.

A little later I noticed that there was a pending edit on the question, so I reviewed it. It needed improvement, so I made a few changes, and then I noticed that [the pending edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26000856) was adding (along with a minor text edit) "*Thanks for the help!*" I have seen posters try to cover their tracks by deleting questions after receiving answers before, but this edit made me think that the OP had posted a homework question using a throwaway account, then deleting that account.

Maybe I just haven't noticed this behavior before, but is this a new kind of abuse? I don't think that we want people to be using one account to create throwaway accounts for the purpose of academic dishonesty. Of course, I have no proof that my interpretation is correct, only suspicion based on the rapid deletion of the account followed by the thank-you edit.

Even if I am wrong about this *particular* case, this seems like an avenue for systemic abuse. How can we prevent such abuse of the system?

Comment: I'm not saying it is not a strange behavior but... How using non-throwaway accounts to post such questions is any different? There is generally no useful correlation between "john" and a  particular student in some CS 101 class of a given school... unless they copy-paste every assignment as a question...

Comment: It's a relatively low-quality question from a new user, and so the risk of the answer simply being ignored is very great, regardless of whether the user deletes their account or not. I don't think "preventing" such abuse (if it can be named such) can be done or will achieve anything. It's just another reason to be selective about which questions to expend time and energy on.

Comment: Certainly not new. Could have been a person who was under 13 as well. Impossible to truly tell from the limited situation presented. That said, you will get used to recognizing these types of situations as you get more familiar with the platform. There is no need to finish someone else's work for them, that was never what Stack Overflow was about.

Comment: The generality of "here is an issue I am having, I expect this, but get that" is something SO helps with very well; that said, a facet of that generality is "here is my homework, I did part of it, and now I need the rest". We should avoid pandering to that subset.

Comment: What is the problem with debugging help on homework questions (work orders would be different)? Or is the homework to debug?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Often a small sample of code is given, and then the student is to finish it for beginner stuff like this. As a result, they have some code to show, so it can appear to be debugging work, but in reality it was just the intro code given during the assignment. It can be difficult to determine how much they threw at it before asking, but with such a small snippet, it is often the case that almost no changes were made to the original starting sample.

Comment: "...is this a new kind of abuse?" I guess it's not new. People probably do it since ages. The advantage seems obvious, all you need is a throwaway email address and some way to get a random IP address, so the system doesn't try to merge your accounts. I simply rarely answer homework questions or question that look like homework. They rarely look useful to me. Often the problem is very contrived.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Update - system doesn't allow this trick anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352669/165773):

> Once a user has posted anything on the site (even if they subsequently delete the post), they will no longer be afforded the immediate account deletion option, and will have to go through the same 24 hour deletion process as everyone else.

---

I think this may indicate a different form of abuse than one you were thinking of - specifically, an attempt to avoid or circumvent asking rate limit / block.

The thing is, when an account is deleted, its posts are disassociated and if done right, this can let one restart with a clean slate no matter how bad their previous posting history was.

The key trick here is to make it fast enough, before getting negative feedback (downvotes, flags, and closure) that could trigger anti-recidivism system [recording account details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/anti-recidivism-system/info) and use it when the account is recreated.

One can ask the next question using the same trick, and again, and again, and again. This "blinking account" approach allows one to stay under the radar of rate limiting systems no matter how many poor posts they made before. If disassociation happens fast enough, it probably even allows to circumvent [90-minutes asking rate limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256324/839601).

One known example of abusing the system like that was [reported at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314617/165773) a while ago:

> <sup>we've been encountering a troll... who... immediately deletes their account after making their trollish post. This allows them to sidestep the Anti-Recidivism System, as it's usually too early for a moderator to arrive and suspend their account, or delete it for abuse, and they effectively get out without any sort of block...</sup>

---

Now, since this indicates possible abuse, it seems natural to suggest you flagging such cases for moderator attention. Unfortunately, I can't recommend that - because in this case I see no way for moderators (nor even for SO development team) to find out about details needed to decide whether it was indeed an abuse or something else.

Comment: Could this kind of abuse be prevented, at least in most blatant cases? Well I can think of few ways how this can be done but this is probably a different story.

Comment: I doubt it can be done automatically without significant technical expense. That said, it should be able to be done manually. For example, if you inspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme%2bracket?tab=newest&page=5&pagesize=50 you may see a pattern.

Comment: @TravisJ to start with, system could keep account details including posts association (at least internally) for 90 minutes after account deletion - this alone would prevent circumventing deault rate limit. Another thing that comes to mind, system could keep hashes of user email and IP mapped to ids of posts associated with it at the moment of deletion so that when account is recreated with prior email or attempts to post from the prior abusive IP this can be detected by hashes. Etc. None of this is rocket science really

Comment: That is assuming they are not using a VPN and different unique emails each time though. At which point, rocket science becomes a little easier to compute than the tool required. Also, I believe they already do much of what you mention, with regards to email, IP, and previous post retention metadata.

Comment: I doubt it would let them circumvent the 90 minute rate limit without adding in a vpn or something, since that's an [IP address limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259942/7795130) rather than account limit. Rest of the answer looks great though.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see this as "abuse"... Ultimately the site does not care who or what asks good non-close-worthy questions - established users, Google bot, aliens, microwaves, one-time users. It is problematic only when accounts post low quality content, get into some sort of vote fraud or troll other users - neither of which (at least based on your estimates) is the case here... and it may even be honest mistake.

If you feel that something  questionable according to the site rules happens - i.e. if the second account you've seen also commented on the question like "good question" it would be good idea to flag your post and explain your concerns. Even in the case of account deletion mods (or at least company employees) would be able to connect those events.

Please note that there is no requirement of "one account per person" in [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) (unlike some other sites). The only requirement for multiple accounts that they don't do vote/rep fraud - [What are the rules governing multiple accounts (i.e. sockpuppets)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388984/what-are-the-rules-governing-multiple-accounts-i-e-sockpuppets).

As [ex-nihilo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6879826/ex-nihilo) pointed out the edit was done to original question by another account which is indeed problematic according to sock-puppets rules. While there could be honest mistake with creating question under wrong account some basic investigation - see if "master" account tend to have many such edits - and flagging for moderator attention if deem problematic. (In this case it does not look like main account has any other activity...)

Comment: Yeah, the microwaves go wild on Seasoned Advice ...

Comment: @exnihilo for some reason I thought that edit was to your answer... Indeed edit to question under such accounts would be a problem, also it is probably grey zone with deleted accounts. ("When I saw something that smelled funny, I should have thought longer before posting here." - I'm not sure what you meant, but the question you asked seem to be perfectly on-topic)