# 20-minute post timer

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions

I understand from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251416/is-it-possible-to-disable-post-questions-once-in-every-20-minute) that since I have <125 rep I cannot post before 20 minutes of my last post.

This seems like a reasonable measure of time to keep the site from being flooded.  But it gets annoying, because I have no way to tell how much longer until I can post again.

Would it be too much to ask to have a little counter next to the `Post Your Question` button telling me how much longer I have to wait?

EDIT: At about the same time, I posted a math question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762571/how-to-find-and-prove-formula-for-area-of-n-gon-with-proof-of-becoming-circle).  Is there a different 20-minute timer for each stackexchange/overflow?

Comment: What message are you getting when you try to post a question to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Its like `You can only post once every 20 minutes`.

Comment: If you follow the link you posted to the end of the link chain, it seems like the limit is 40 minutes, network wide(at least according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900) (so yup your math question would trigger that) if you are under 125. As to a timer... I would just count an hour after your last question, seems safe enough it shouldn't be an issue :)

Comment: I don't think that's the error message you're getting.

Comment: Have you thought about using...a clock?

Answer (score 11):

This isn't a direct answer, but I think it should be said: really, you shouldn't need to post more than once every 20 minutes.

To make a good, useful post that will be well recieved, you should be spending at least that just writing the question, let alone the debugging and research that should have preceded the question, and the editing before the question is posted. Honestly, I spend at least half an hour on any question I ask to make sure that it's not a duplicate, that I've provided enough information, and people with less context than me can actually understand what I'm asking.

I don't think anyone should ever even hit that 20 minute restriction, and if they do, I'd take that as a sign that more care needs to be taken when asking questions. If you take that into consideration, this question becomes a non-problem.

Honestly, I think the limit should be much higher, like once per hour. I don't think I've seen enough spamming to justify that change, but I think it's entirely reasonable.

Comment: I could not possibly work hard enough to generate questions at that frequency. I would have to have a pre-prepared list of questions, kinda like an exam paper.

Comment: @MartinJames My thoughts exactly. I've stayed up late after an hour of writing a question just to put finishing touches down. 20 minutes to write an entire question seems ridiculously short.

Comment: Well, given that the OP is asking maths questions too, my guess would be a homework factor, posting questions for a set of customers:(

Answer (score 4):

It has been quite some time since I was at <125 rep but may I ask why it is not sufficient to check your [**questions tab**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9609025/mackycheese21?tab=questions&sort=newest) and sort it by newest?

If I am thoroughly oblivious to something here then someone please shed some light.

In any case, I agree with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367094/2191572

Answer (score 1):

Really, a good implementation what you propose, but at the same time it is unnecessary, for the following reasons:

1 - Generally, in those 40 minutes, your previous question will be answered or answered.

2 - There is no need for the site to tell you how much is needed for the 40 minutes to pass, since you can use a clock or a timer.

Regarding your second question, the answer is YES, each site of Stack Exchage is different, if you have noticed, if you win +15 rep in Stack Overflow, you will see that for example in another site of the network to which you are subscribed as you can be WorldBuilding, your reputation is still 1, that is a clear example that each site (except Meta that is related to Stack Overflow) is independent of others.

Comment: Except.... The link actively says '40 minutes between posts **on the network**'... So I am not sure if you are correct here